# Make children divs the height of tallest child

Tags: css

I have two child `<div>` elements inside of a parent container `<div>` as shown:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Sup?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Sup?</p>
        <p>Wish that other guy was the same height as me</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following CSS:

```
.item {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: inline-block;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

How can I get both children (`div.item`) to be the height of the tallest child?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m4f7/

Comment: This question has been asked a multitude of times.  See this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592597/issue-with-responsive-columns-having-equal-height

Comment: Simple. Easy. [Equal Height Columns with Flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One solution is to change the display value from `inline-block` to `table-cell` for the descendant `div.item` elements:

```
.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 20px; /* For controlling spacing between cells... */
}
.item {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m4f7/6/)

Comment: Careful, table-cell is a css3 and doesnt work in all browsers.

Comment: Actually the `table-cell` value was introduced in the [CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)

Comment: Please add  display: table and border-spacing: 20px 20px to .row in your fiddle, makes the columns more apparent, thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7m4f7/5/

Comment: and for those who wonder why this doesn't work for you. make sure you have not set a float rule. You can have `float: none`

Because sometimes we use float to eliminate carriage return spaces with `inline-block`.

Comment: Kudos to Jomar for that extra tip-- totally helped!

Answer (score 13):

Another solution is to use flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/7m4f7/4/

```
.item {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

However, support is limited (but getting better!) See http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Otherwise you need to use javascript to set the heights manually.

Comment: given it does work, suppose that I have a lot of child elements that were divided automatically into different lines when I used `inline-block` but now it all gets stuffed in one line. Is there a work around for that.

Comment: @akabhirav, yes — use `flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row;`

Answer (score 10):

jquery version: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr48S/)**

```
var maxheight = 0;

$('div div.y').each(function () {
    maxheight = ($(this).height() > maxheight ? $(this).height() : maxheight); 
});

$('div div.y').height(maxheight);
```

EDIT: Just noticed you're not dealing with the height of `<div>`'s, but `<p>`'s

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid:

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Sup?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Sup?</p>
        <p>Wish that other guy was the same height as me</p>
    </div>
</div>
```