# Viewport height 100% not working on page element

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have no idea why my border stops before the bottom of the page. **I have tried lots of things: clearing floats, 100%, jQuery, vh, vmax** + I have read other questions from stackoverflow but always it stops before the bottom.

I have two divs `section.left` and `section.middle`. I am trying to get an `8 px` border on the `section.left` div to go from the top of the page to the bottom. But it stops if the page gets longer.

See [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGgeWR)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="left">
        <header>
            <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="images/smallImage1.jpg" alt="Logo"></a>
        </header>
        <div class="intro">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis,</p>
            <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="skills">
            <h6>Skills</h6>
            <ul>
                <li>Skill 1</li>
                <li>Skill 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>2016 - Site 1</p>
        </footer>
    </section>
    <section class="midle">
        <div class="post">
                <h2>Headline</h2>
                <img src="images/bigImage1.jpg" alt="Big image">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis, lacinia quis facilisis sed sapien. Mauris varius diam vitae arcu. Sed arcu lectus auctor vitae,</p>
                <img src="images/bigImage2.jpg" alt="Big image">
                <img src="images/smallImage1.jpg" alt="Small image">
                <img src="images/bigImage1.jpg" alt="Big image">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed posuere interdum sem. Quisque ligula eros ullamcorper quis, lacinia quis facilisis sed sapien. Mauris varius diam vitae arcu. Sed arcu lectus auctor vitae,</p>
                <img src="images/bigImage2.jpg" alt="Big image">
        </div>
    </section>
</div> <!-- END OF WRAPPER -->
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1700px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*---------------- END OF BASE ------------------------*/

section{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

/*---------------- SECTION LEFT ------------------------*/

section.left{
    width: 20%;
    padding: 4% 2%;
    height: 100vmax;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 8px solid #60689D;
}

/*---------------- SECTION MIDLE ------------------------*/

section.midle{
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: did you apply clearfix to wrapper?

Comment: @markoddden I have tried that but did nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about setting the `.left` border to `transparent` and adding a pseudo element that will serve as a border instead.

```
.wrapper:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 4% 2%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 8px solid #60689D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

See [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WradXL)

This way regardless which one between `.left` and `.right` is longer, the border will always reach the bottom of `.wrapper`

Comment: Clever, why not remove the border from section.left then?

Comment: @DigitalDouble One big problem is that i cant click any links.

Comment: Oh yeah because the the pseudo element will be on top of the `.left`. The code snippet actually sets a `z-index: 2;` on `.sections`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

- Remove `height: 100vmax` from `section.left`
- Add `display: flex` to `.wrapper`

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxqpdV?editors=1100)

---

*Explanation:*

Under the rules of CSS **Flexbox**, child elements (aka, flex items) will automatically stretch the full length of the [cross-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276) of the flex container. (This is why flexbox is great for equal height columns.) However, a `height` rule on a flex item will override this default setting. So we remove that rule.

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Equal Height Columns with Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Answer (score 2):

### **EDIT**

CSS Table solution: [taken from css- Make children divs the height of tallest child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594891/make-children-divs-the-height-of-tallest-child)

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1700px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table; /* display parent as table */
}

section.left {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 4% 2%;
  height: 100vmax;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 8px solid #60689D;
  display: table-cell; /* make child as table-cell */
  float:none; /* no floating! */
  vertical-align:top; /* align content to top */
}

section.middle {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  display: table-cell; /* make child as table-cell */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[CodePen fork](http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/XXxVZm)

---

### Quick solution

assumes the middle section is always longer

```
section.middle {
    border-left:8px solid #60689D;
}
```

See [Codepen fork](http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/gPBoGe)

Comment: oh I see, this is regarding a column not being the same height as the other column, I would approach this differently and have the longer column get the border property

Comment: sometimes the `section.left` is longer than `section.middle`. I can't put the border on `section.middle`

Comment: Ok in that case you could try the table solution (updated answer) taken from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594891/make-children-divs-the-height-of-tallest-child