# Equal height columns with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I would like to use percentage for my css table. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

What's wrong with this code? Should I use flexbox instead of table?

I would like to use table, because I would like same height columns.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So you want the list items to be half the width of the window? Then the ul would be 300% wide, not 100%. You choose: either the percentages add up to the correct numbers, or you will need to leave out one of the values and let the browser calculate the width itself.

Comment: Do I undestand you corretly that you're trying to get two list items next to each other and next ones should appear in the next line?

Comment: You cant break columns into multiple lines without wrapping them with rows. You have to use flexbox for this, here is my visual guide for beginners http://prettyminimal.com/flexbox .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample using `ul`/`li` elements, 2 columns using percentage and have equal height.

As tables prefer table/row/cell layout, I restructured your html a little.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
  height: 60%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
  display: table-row;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

### Equal Height Columns with Flexbox

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { display: flex; }
```

With the simple code above, you can put any amount of content in a list item, and all list items will have equal height.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuwqsrab/18/)

---

*Notes:*

- An initial setting of a flex container is [`flex-direction: row`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property), which means that child elements (aka, flex items) will line up horizontally.
- Another initial setting of a flex container is [`align-items: stretch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property), which causes flex items to expand the full height (or width, depending on `flex-direction`), of the container.
- Together, both settings above create equal height columns.
- Flex equal height columns apply only to siblings.
- Applying a height to a flex item overrides the equal height feature.
- [Equal height columns apply only to flex items on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36004926/3597276).
- [How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33034660/3597276)

---

***Browser support:*** *Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Answer (score 0):

I'm throwing up an answer to an interpretation of the question that differs from @Michael_B.  With the initial style of `width: 50%;` on the `li` elements, I'm thinking the desired result is to have the six list-items flow into 2 columns and 3 rows.  Such a case cannot be readily solved using CSS tables but is relatively simple with flexbox.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*kills the irritating intial padding on uls in webkit*/
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*stretch is the default value, but it will force items to stretch to match others in their row*/
  align-items: stretch;
  /*below properties just emphasize the layout*/
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
li {
  /*forces border-width and padding to be part of the declared with (50% in this case)*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  /*list-item, inline-block, and block work equally well*/
  display: list-item;
  /*below properties just emphasize the layout*/
  border: white 2px solid;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
/*I set this property to show what happens if 1 item has a different height*/

li:nth-child(3) {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```