# css Float left and Float right issue

Tags: css

I am trying to split a div into two event columns. The first div should be aligned left and the second div should be aligned right.

My solution is basically the following...

```
    <div style="width:100%;>            
        <div style="width:50%; float:left;">

        </div>
        <div style="width:50%; float:right;">

        </div>          
    </div>
```

My second column (my button panel) is going on a new line. I'm fairly new to css so help with a quick explanation would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/ff2yo9n3/

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "My second column (my button panel) is going on a new line." ?

Comment: If you look at [this updated fiddle (added colors)](https://jsfiddle.net/ff2yo9n3/4/), the columns are displaying correctly (though this is not the best way).

Comment: @Park Soon Wai... that leaves the underline looking wrong

Comment: @Richie do you mean the `border-bottom` of `.header`? Or do you want to achieve equal height in both `div`s?

Comment: yes. I want that border bottom to underline the heading and also the buttons. But in that fiddle it has moved up through the text.

Comment: @Richie I see. That is another issue when the children of a `div` are all floated. You need to add `clearfix` to the parent `div` when this happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to CSS, why not learn a modern layout technique with a broad range of options (flexbox), as opposed to an older method which has limited capacity and was never intended for building layouts (floats)?

With CSS3 [**Flexible Boxes (flexbox)**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can build your layout quickly, simply and efficiently.

Here's all you need:

**HTML** (removed inline styles)

```
<div class="header">
    <div>Buttons</div>
    <div>
        <a data-code="button" title="Show Source" class="top-button">
           <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (added two lines of code)

```
.box .header {
    font-weight:300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: normal;

    /* new */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ff2yo9n3/5/)

Flexbox benefits:

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. [it's the future of CSS layouts](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/)

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: thank you. Yes I like this answer. I'm going to pursue this.

Comment: I've been playing with flex. I really like it and am really glad that I'm learning the new way to do it rather than the old way. Thanks again for your post.

Comment: FYI, here's a good flexbox video tutorial on YouTube: [*What the flexbox?*](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) There are also some on Lynda.com, but you'll need to pay subscription.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the div into two 50% width elements, you can't go the way you did there.

Both has to have the same floating element or else they will be overlapping with each other. This is a broad topic that is explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), referred as Block Formatting Context.

What you may want to do instead, make both divs to `float: left;` and `width: 50%;` then set the `text-align: right;` for the right aligned div.

Comment: I tried that here... https://jsfiddle.net/LjqczL46/1/ ... But it didn't work for me. I will have a read of your link.

Comment: You missed a closing `"` on your fiddle there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LjqczL46/3/  That seems to work but  had to add a clear both. I'm struggling with clear:both. Would you know why clear both is required in this scenario?

Comment: This is a different question :)
At this point, think of `float` property is like a dimension of it's own. When you have a parent element and a child inside that don't share the same `float` property, they are now in a different world. Hence the parent won't be able to acknowledge that there is a child inside of it.