# How to align two floating HTML tags with word wrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align two floating HTML element facing the correct one on the other side.
HTML below is more clear.

```css
label{
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  padding-right:2.5%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  background:red;
}
span{
  float:right;
  width:75%;
  padding-left:2.5%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <label>OrderId:</label>
    <span>4857924875928475924</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Comment:</label>
 <span>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>User:</label>
    <span>User_Name</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Above script misalign the User: User_Name when comment is long enough.

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to display all of the comment's text?

Comment: Yeah, I have to display all the characters. Usually it not too long in my case but long enough to cause this issue in some cases.

Comment: use table with two columns. This case is about 'two equal height column css'.

Comment: You can either use a table or use `display: table-cell`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your **p** `tag` `p{overflow:hidden;}`

Becuase you used **floating** **element** just clear your `p` `tag`

```css
label{
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  padding-right:2.5%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  background:red;
}
p{overflow:hidden;}
span{
  float:right;
  width:75%;
  padding-left:2.5%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <label>OrderId:</label>
    <span>4857924875928475924</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Comment:</label>
 <span>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>User:</label>
    <span>User_Name</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

**[more about this](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**

Comment: i also suggest use clearfix in parent tag when you are floating elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve equal height columns with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**HTML** (no changes)

**CSS**

```
p {
  display: flex;
}

label {
  flex: 1 1 20%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background: red;
}

span {
  flex: 1 1 75%;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background: green;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4uevLgz/)

Flexbox benefits:

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*