# 3-column divs with dynamic middle - right div dropping down

Tags: html, css

Started a project involving a 3-column div at the top - 300px/dynamic/350px.  The right div falls below the others:  http://jsfiddle.net/tspencer103/b49mfno4/1/.

I have tries several suggestions here like http://jsfiddle.net/22YBU/.  No luck.  Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
 div #div_1 {
   float: left;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   width: 300px;
 }

 div #div_2 {
   height: 50px;
   margin: 0px 350px 0px 300px;
   background-color: green;
   text-align: center;
 }

 div #div_3 {
   float: right;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: blue;
   width: 350px;
 }

 <div id="container">
    <div id="div_1">LEFT STATIC 300px</div>
    <div id="div_2">CENTER DYNAMIC</div>
    <div id="div_3">RIGHT STATIC 350px</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in a simple, more modern approach, drop the floats and use [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

**HTML** (no changes)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div_1">LEFT STATIC 300px</div>
    <div id="div_2">CENTER DYNAMIC</div>
    <div id="div_3">RIGHT STATIC 350px</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container { 
  display: flex;
  }

#div_1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 50px;
  }

#div_2 { 
  background-color: green; 
  text-align: center;  
  height: 50px; 
  flex: 1; /* flexible width */
  }

#div_3 { 
  background-color: blue; 
  width: 350px; 
  height: 50px;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b49mfno4/5/)

Flexbox benefits:

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Great suggestion.  You prefer Flexbox over Bootstrap?  Still curious how to "fix" the original code.

Comment: Yes, I prefer flexbox over bootstrap (which I've rarely ever used). Flexbox comes directly from the W3C and is, in my view, the future off CSS layouts.

Comment: Here's one way to solve your problem based on your original code... (basically, make child divs `inline-block` and use [**calc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to size flexible div) ... http://jsfiddle.net/b49mfno4/8/

Comment: Wow.  That was easy :)  Thanks, Michael.