# how to precisely adjust children divs to parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a father div which holds 3 children divs, I try to adjust the 3 divs to the father width but I have a little gap after the third div, how can I solve it ?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="main">
      <div id="first" style="width:100%;float:left">
           <div>1</div>
           <div>2</div>
           <div>3</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: double;
}

div#first> div{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fcLey4jz/  like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  border: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* which give padding and border from inside */
  border-style: double;
}

/* i have used below code to clear the floats 
   or you can also use <div class="clear"></div> to clear the floats
*/

#first:after,
#first:before {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

div#first > div {
  width: 33.33%; /* changed the width from 33% to 33.33% */
  background: red;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first"> <!-- no need to add because i have cleared the floats and also by default div is a block element it will take 100% -->
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this layout very simply with [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="first">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#first { display: flex; }
div#first > div { flex: 1; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/L81hwjya/2/)

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

To learn more about flexbox visit:

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: It looks awesome! but i'm using css3 and all the flex options i get using the display are:   display:inline-flexbox;
   display:flexbox, and not FLEX. and it doesn't work... not this way

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. My answer is pure CSS3. If you could explain further maybe I could adjust my answer.

Comment: I added to my css code :
div#first {
   display:inline-flexbox; 
}
and  flex:1; to div#first> div
and nothing is changed.. although your demo works, it doesn't work in my project..

Comment: I use css3 VS 2013 and these are my only 'flex' options, maybe i'm missing something..

Answer (score 0):

```
div:last-child{
   margin:0px !important;
   padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Because you have a Border you might need to reduce to 32% width to accommodate the pixels.

Comment: Also you might need #first > div

Comment: You can do decimal as well.  32.5%, etc.

Comment: better use a generic way to solve this problem in my case.