# Center a div over another div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I added a landing page to my webapp, so when it is loading data from the server, the landing page is shown with a loading image and a description.

```
  <div class="map_view">
    <!-- shown only when data is not available -->
    <div class="loading_screen">
      <img src="/img/loading_boys.gif"/>
      <h2>Connecting to the the network ...</h2>
    </div>;
  </div>
```

The div `loading screen` is on top of div `map_view`. I want to center the image and the `<h2>` on its parent div. I can use `text-align: center;` to center it horizontally. But I cannot find a way to center it vertically. I want to make it compatible to different screen sizes as well, so no matter in what devices, the loading div is always in the center of its parent div.

I tried to use `display: table;` in `map_view` and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on `loading_screen`, but then the google map disappears, with just a background color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
.loading_screen {
    display: flex;            /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: column;   /* align children vertically (column format) */
    justify-content: center;  /* center children vertically */
    align-items: center;      /* center column horizontally */
}
```

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, 
       flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It did center the img and the <h2>. But the <h2> content was pushed to the right of the image, I want it to be behind the image. It also caused the image to be stretched horizontally. Deleting the <h2> solves all of the above. I wonder how to fix it in another way?

Comment: Add this line of code: `flex-direction: column`. See revised code block in my answer.

Comment: Worked like magic... I'll study the code to see why it works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Here's a good resource if you're interested: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this trick to centre stuff perfectly in websites. Just have to emphasise that this will only work if the outer container has a defined height.

---

*Make sure the .loading_screen (container) has a fixed height in pixels and the apply this css to the img and h2 (contents):*

```
.loading_screen {                                      
    height: 500px; /*for example*/                     /* Container */
}    

h2 {                                                   
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;                                          /* Content */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

*Adjust the translate to move elements up or down in container. -50% centres it.*

*Use -moz- -o- and -webkit- prefixes on the 'transform: ' for browser compatibility:*

```
transform: translateY();
-webkit-transform: translateY();
-o-transform: translateY();
-moz-transform: translateY();
```

---

You could use:

```
.loading_screen {
    display: flex;            
    justify-content: center;  
    align-items: center;      
    align-content: center;   
}
```

But it has very awkward and undesirable effects when dealing with multiple stacks of elements.