# How to make <td> elements in table same height?

Tags: css, html, html-table, cell

I know there are many questions about this, but I have an other set-up than most people. I have a one-row table that moves with my page. See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evk49ey1/1/

html:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <td>a</td>
    <td id="b">b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
    <td id="j">j</td>
    <td>k</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
td{
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
background-color: #3399ff;
height: 50px;
width: 75px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
td:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #1177dd;
}

#b{
  height: 80px;
}

#j{
  height:90px;
}
```

I want a css and html only solution. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is what I have till now:https://jsfiddle.net/evk49ey1/3/

The cells have all the same height, also when you change the content of one cell the others will follow along.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

And now I want that the cells g, h, i, j and k just get an height of 50px, because they are not next to cell a which needs more height.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you want them all to be the same height and have a maximum height like 90px?

Comment: Equal heights: simple and easy with flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Comment: @Narek-T, no that is not what I want. See the EDIT: section in my question for an image of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Michael_B, I don't think that is going to solve my problem. See the EDIT: section in my question for an image of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think this is possible, but not with tables. You need to use flexbox.
Here is my example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.inner {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  width: 75px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #1177dd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">b</div>
  <div class="inner">c</div>
  <div class="inner">d</div>
  <div class="inner">e</div>
  <div class="inner">f</div>
  <div class="inner">g</div>
  <div class="inner">h</div>
  <div class="inner">i</div>
  <div class="inner">j</div>
```

And [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/b0yp58yo/). When you resize window you can see it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if i really understand your question, but if you need all the `tds` to be the same height, i would wrap them into a `tr`, like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/evk49ey1/2/

give the tr a height (auto uses the tallest td height as row height) , and then `td` height to be 100% of it's parent (`tr`)

```
tr{height:auto;}
td{height:100%}
```

For "b" and "J" you are setting a different height, i don't know if it's wanted or not. That's the reason why they have a different height

**EDIT**

There is a bit of confusion..
css is a language that doesn't allow dynamic changes, as when you deploy a project, all the style and how the page needs to be displayed is already there and ready to be used.

If you need to dynamically change a css value, you have no other option that javascript.

Comment: I want that all of the divs in the row get the same height as the tallest

Comment: so my fiddle works, just remove the #b style and they are all the same height

Comment: if you change #j style as well, you can see that all the tds are the same height as you put into #j

Comment: but if I set the td height to 100px and the #j height to 200px, all of the other divs are not 200px.

Comment: if you want to have all the same height, why would you set one do be double the height? if you want dynamic change, you cannot do it with html/css only, but you must use javascript

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

1. It's missing `<tr>` tag, which is invalid HTML.
2. Remove `display: inline-block;` on the `td`, it breaks the default table layout, and prevents the cells from matching height.
3. `border-collapse: collapse;` must be set on `table`, not `td`.
4. Since you have different `height` set on the cell, it will find the tallest one and applies it to rest of cells. If you don't have any `height` defined, it will be decided by the content. Again, it always matches the tallest one.
5. If you need fixed cell width, and with known number of cells, let's say 11, `75px` width for each. Set a width on the `table` of `75x11=825px`.

Updated code below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; /*added*/
  width: 825px; /*added*/
}
td {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* display: inline-block; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
}

td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #1177dd;
}

#b {
  height: 80px;
}

#j {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td id="b">b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td>i</td>
      <td id="j">j</td>
      <td>k</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```