# How to calculate div height using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have develop some html page. I want to fit side menu when change page div height

```
<div>  <!-- menu div-->
</div> 
<div>  <!-- content div-->
</div>
```

When change **content div** height, want to change same height in menu div. When show hidden field change content div height, I want to adjust menu div height in same height. I looking for answer in **jquery** or **JavaScript**.

Comment: `$('div').height();`

Comment: If you want to work with specific divs you will need to apply ID's to them. You can use pseudo-elements but it's not a good practice for this case.

Comment: take a look at this [Equal height for two divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342576/equal-height-for-two-divs/35342898#35342898)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vtowh2ce/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See about 
https://api.jquery.com/resize/
and http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
$('div').height();
```

or

```
$('div').resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind/trigger` for that:

```
$('#content-div').bind('heightChange', function(event, newHeight){
  $('#main-div').height(newHeight);
});
```

and trigger event on div height change:

```
var newHeight = 200;
$('#content-div').css('height', newHeight);
$("#content-div").trigger('heightChange', newHeight);
```