# How can I apply max-width to a text div, but have the div expand only as much as it has to?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If you apply a `max-width` and `display:inline-block;` to a div with text in it, the div will expand only as wide as the text is, until the text is so wide that a new line has to be started. Past this point, the div will take the maximum width allowed, regardless of how wide the widest line of text actually is.

My point is illustrated in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nx570uu6/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    wordswordswords wordswordswords wordswordswords 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  background:blue;
}

.item {
  max-width:90%;
  background:green;
  margin:5px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Is there a way to make the div only as wide as the widest line of text?

So instead of this:

```
|wordswordswords            |
|wordswordswordswords       |
|wordswords                 |
```

The div would look like this:

```
|wordswordswords     |
|wordswordswordswords|
|wordswords          |
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do [*equal height columns*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276) and, as requested here, *equal width rows*. Try this:

```
 body {
      display: flex;            /* make .wrapper only as wide as longest content */
 }

.wrapper {
     display: flex;             
     flex-direction: column;    /* stack flex items vertically */
     /* width: 200px; */
     height: 400px;
     /* background: blue; */
}

.item {
    /* max-width: 90%; */
    background: chartreuse;     /* adjusted color; easier to see text */
    margin: 5px 0;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

NOTES:

- Now all `.item` divs will be equal width.The longest div sets the width for all.
- In order for this method to work, you'll need to remove all specified widths, as they override the flex [`align-items: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) rule, which creates the equal width rows.
- If you want the rows to be a maximum width of 90% of the parent, instead of `max-width: 90%` on the child, try `padding-right: 10%` on the parent.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nx570uu6/7/)

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but it didn't work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nx570uu6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Go for display: flex; in your wrapper class as it will ensure that they are all the same width.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but that doesn't work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nx570uu6/3/

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to size inline-blocks is called [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) or [fit-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fit-content-measure):

```
min(max-content, max(min-content, fill-available))
```

where the `max-content` is the preferred size without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and the `min-content` is breaking lines in all soft wrap opportunities.

Then, when `min-content < fill-available < max-content`, the shrink-to-fit width is `fill-available`. Instead, you want it to be the maximum width of the contents in each line box.

AFAIK, there is no way to achieve this. The reasoning might be that a small tiny change could rearrange the items into different lines, and produce a big abrupt change in the width of the container. This is probably undesirable. It could also produce circular definitions, e.g. in case the width of the children is in percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply `width:min-content` ?

```css
.wrapper {
  width:200px;
  background:gold;
}

.item {
  width:min-content;
  background:green;
  margin:5px 0;
  display:block;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    wordswordswords word wordswordswordswords 
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the div from growing to a width more than 90% of its parent?

Answer (score 0):

you may use the `display:table` or `display:inline-table;` propertie. shrinks/expands to fit to inside content.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.item {
  /*max-width:90%; here ?  it breaks ! */
  background: green;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    wordswordswords word wordswordswordswords
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    wordswordswords word
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    wordswordswords
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    words
  </div>
</div>
```