# Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

I gather that this is impossible to achieve using Flexbox, as each row can only be the minimal height required to fit its elements, but can this be achieved using the newer CSS Grid?

To be clear, I want equal height for all elements in a grid across all rows, not just per each row. Basically, the highest "cell" should dictate the height of all cells, not just the cells in its row.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

### Short Answer

If the goal is to create a grid with equal height rows, where the tallest cell in the grid sets the height for all rows, here's a quick and simple solution:

- Set the container to  `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`

---

### How it works

Grid Layout provides a unit for establishing flexible lengths in a grid container. This is the [**`fr`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit) unit. It is designed to distribute free space in the container and is somewhat analogous to the `flex-grow` property in flexbox.

If you set all rows in a grid container to `1fr`, let's say like this:

```
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
```

... then all rows will be equal height.

It doesn't really make sense off-the-bat because `fr` is supposed to distribute free space. And if several rows have content with different heights, then when the space is distributed, some rows would be proportionally smaller and taller.

***Except***, buried deep in the grid spec is this little nugget:

> [**7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the `fr`
>   unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
>
> ...
>
> When the available space is infinite (which happens when the grid
>   container’s width or height is indefinite), flex-sized (`fr`) grid tracks are
>   sized to their contents while retaining their respective proportions.
>
> The used size of each flex-sized grid track is computed by determining
>   the `max-content` size of each flex-sized grid track and dividing that
>   size by the respective flex factor to determine a “hypothetical `1fr`
>   size”.
>
> The maximum of those is used as the resolved `1fr` length (the
>   flex fraction), which is then multiplied by each grid track’s flex
>   factor to determine its final size.

So, if I'm reading this correctly, when dealing with a dynamically-sized grid (e.g., the height is indefinite), grid tracks (rows, in this case) are sized to their contents.

The height of each row is determined by the tallest ([`max-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-columns-max-content)) grid item.

The maximum height of those rows becomes the length of `1fr`.

That's how `1fr` creates equal height rows in a grid container.

---

### Why flexbox isn't an option

As noted in the question, equal height rows are not possible with flexbox.

Flex items can be equal height on the same row, but not across multiple rows.

This behavior is defined in the flexbox spec:

> [**6. Flex Lines**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-lines)
>
> In a multi-line flex container, the cross size of each line is the minimum size necessary to contain the flex items on the line.

In other words, when there are multiple lines in a row-based flex container, the height of each line (the "cross size") is the minimum height necessary to contain the flex items on the line.

Comment: In the mentioned paragraph, what does this portion exactly mean: "and dividing that size by the respective flex factor to determine a “hypothetical 1fr size".
For example, if the highest size in the first row of a grid container was 100px and the `grid-auto-row` for that row was 2, does this means the size of 1fr for the first row is equal to 50px?

Comment: To achieve same height boxes in multiple rows we should use CSS grid instead of CSS flex is that right ?

Comment: @moshiuramit Correct

Comment: What if the goal is to create a grid with equal height rows, where the shortest cell sets the height for all rows?

Comment: Doesn't work if images are in the items

Answer (score 60):

The short answer is that setting `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` on the grid container solves what was asked.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.description {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}

.col {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Hlsg/pen/EXKJba)

Comment: Thanks for the codepen, the explanation in michael's answer is great but the codepen shows me exactly what I need to do.

Comment: If you have <ul> objects with <li>'s inside this doesn't work

Comment: If the child of the grid is also a grid, then it will not work - changing the child to flex will make it work.