# How to stretch height equally on all flex items in column direction?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have flex items `.item` with `flex-direction: column` and I want each child item (`.item__title`, `.item__description`) to take equal vertical space depending on the highest one. So next item starts with same new row. I' trying following code:

```
<article class="items">
<section class="item">
    <h2 class="item__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p class="item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <a class="item__more-button">See more</a>
</section>
<section class="item">
    <h2 class="item__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p class="item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="item__more-button">See more</a>
</section>
<section class="item">
    <h2 class="item__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt</h2>
    <p class="item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="item__more-button">See more</a>
</section>
</article>


  .items {
  display: flex;
  }

  .item {
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: calc((100% - 2 * 15px) / 3);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  }



  .item__title {
      flex: 1;
  }

  .item__description {
      flex: 1;
  }
```

But I want it to look like this picture:

[image]

How can I do this without setting heights?

Comment: can you share css code too

Comment: that's not possible with flexbox if *title* or *description* heights are dynamic... you will have to at least set height for *title* or *description*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` with `display:grid` for parent section and do not forget to set width to 100% for child section. Otherwise it's not going to give you what you want.

Working jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e63k17na/

**UPDATE:**

After looking at the screenshot I believe you want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/e63k17na/1/

Just apply the same logic into subclass, which is "item" in this case.

```
.items{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
    text-align:center;
  }

.item{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work as I want, look at screenshot in my question

Answer (score 1):

just add justify-content: space-between; to your item class, 
your sections already have the same heigth

```css
  .items {
  display: flex;
  }

  .item {
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: calc((100% - 2 * 15px) / 3);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
.item.__title{
flex:1;
}
.item.__description {
      flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<article class="items">
<section class="item">
    <h2 class="item__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p class="item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <a class="item__more-button">See more</a>
</section>
<section class="item">
    <h2 class="item__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p class="item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="item__more-button">See more</a>
</section>
<section class="item">
    <h2 class="item__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt</h2>
    <p class="item__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="item__more-button">See more</a>
</section>
</article>
```

Comment: It didn't help.