# Correct implementation of CSS Grid in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

As concluded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout), CSS Grid implement equal height elements across rows by using `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`. However, Chrome and Firefox manifest different behaviours when inserting rows with a height set to auto between the equal height rows. That is, Chrome achieves equal height across rows when using the explicit `grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 1fr` syntax but only equal height on a per row basis when using `repeat` like `grid-auto-rows: auto repeat(3, 1fr);` while Firefox only achieves equal height on a per row basis regardless.

Please observe the following in both Firefox and Chrome:

https://codepen.io/Hlsg/pen/eemRmm

https://codepen.io/Hlsg/pen/jGWQwM

Interestingly, they both behave the same with this implementation, so I'm thinking this is more to do with their implementation of `css repeat`:

https://codepen.io/Hlsg/pen/VWKPzq

What's your take on this, and which browser do you think has the correct, standard aproach?

Answer (score 1):

> Interestingly, they both behave the same with this implementation, so I'm thinking this is more to do with their implementation of css `repeat`.

I think you're correct.

If you look at the spec definition for `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns`, the `repeat()` notation does not appear to be an acceptable value.

The definition says that only track sizes are acceptable values. And the definition of "track size" does not include `repeat()`.

So a violation of the spec or, at a minimum, unclear spec language, may lead to differing browser implementations.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks

Comment: So you're saying that with `repeat` both browsers are operating out of spec, so none of them are right or wrong. So there wouldn't be any point in filing a bugreport with either. If that's teh case, I think you should update the thread mentioned in my OP as it's quite popular and this info can save alot of headaches.

Comment: My answer is based on my reading of the spec. I'm pretty sure I'm correct, but I'm not a spec writer or browser maker, so I may be misinterpreting key terms or syntax. I wouldn't go any further than my answer at this point, so I'll leave your post as-is for now. Maybe somebody else can shed some more light on this behavior.