# How to auto size rows to fit the container in css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Please see the code below. How can I divide the inner box into six equal height rows? I know that something like this can be acheived with columns in `display: grid` using `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(,)`

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #ced9d5;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item div {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item01"></div>
      <div class="item02"></div>
      <div class="item03"></div>
      <div class="item04"></div>
      <div class="item05"></div>
      <div class="item06"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column` on the container, and stretch the items to fill the available space using `flex: 1 0 auto` on the items.

```css
* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outerbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.innerbox {
    width: 40vh;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: #ced9d5;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item div {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">

  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="item">

      <div class="item01"></div>
      <div class="item02"></div>
      <div class="item03"></div>
      <div class="item04"></div>
      <div class="item05"></div>
      <div class="item06"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with Grid.

Here are a few options:

```
grid-auto-rows: auto /* default setting; very simple: nothing to define */
```

```css
.outerbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #ced9d5;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.item div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item01"></div>
      <div class="item02"></div>
      <div class="item03"></div>
      <div class="item04"></div>
      <div class="item05"></div>
      <div class="item06"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
grid-auto-rows: 1fr
```

```css
.outerbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #ced9d5;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.item div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item01"></div>
      <div class="item02"></div>
      <div class="item03"></div>
      <div class="item04"></div>
      <div class="item05"></div>
      <div class="item06"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The solution above is explained here: [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Or you can set the row heights explicitly, like this:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr)
```

```css
.outerbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: #ced9d5;
}

.item {
  display: grid;                         
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  height: 100%;                          
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);  /* distribute the space in the container equally
                                          among six rows */
}

.item div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item01"></div>
      <div class="item02"></div>
      <div class="item03"></div>
      <div class="item04"></div>
      <div class="item05"></div>
      <div class="item06"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```