# First row a finite size, variable remaining rows equal portions of remaining space?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm attempting to have a CSS Grid in which the `grid-template-rows` have the following definition:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
}
```

Now obviously, the above doesn't work. I hope that my erroneous code shows what I'm *intending* to do well enough. To put it in English: first row I want to be (for sake of example) 20 pixels in height; the variable (non-definite; could be 2, could be 20) remaining rows should be equal portions of the remaining height. Can someone tell me why the above *doesn't* work, and what (if anything) *will* do what I'm intending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the first row is definite, you don't need to use `grid-template-rows` to define all rows that may exist in the grid.

The first row can exist in the *explicit grid* (sized by `grid-template-rows`).

The remaining rows can exist in the *implicit grid* (sized by `grid-auto-rows`).

Instead of this:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
}
```

Try this:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* also try `auto` (which is the default) */
}
```

Also see: [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Comment: Really sorry I never got back to up-voting or selecting your answer, @Michael Benjamin! Just did so. 