# `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` doesn't have the expected effect

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My HTML and CSS code are [in this jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/mcoulont/h0nwxqeo/7/)

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout), as the element `<span class="premises" style="grid-template-columns:auto auto ;">` has `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`, the two `<span class="premise">` items should have equal heights.

On my browsers, it's not the case at all (and it's quite visible in Firefox).

Does anyone know why?

Comment: you set 5 auto rows for the first child span, so it draws each element into a row and text aside tag element are virtually wrapped into a container. that makes 3 rows, next span is also set as a grid of 5 rows. What is the expected result ? are children supposed to be grids too ?

Comment: You only have **one** row in the upper grid