# Set grid items to be same height

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

[image: this four-card layout] I have quite a specific issue with grid. I was trying to make with all grid items the same size. `stretch` is not an option in this case, because some of the items span across two rows. When I added `align-items: center`, that didn't solve the issue. I really didn't find anything to be of help.

```css
#cards {
  padding: 0 7vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card:nth-child(1),
.card:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px -15px hsl(215, 49%, 82%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 3</h2>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 4</h2>
      <p>I built this two line paragraph oh yes I really want it to be two lines or yes finally.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your ideas.
(I am new on Stack Overflow so feel free to give any other suggestions to help me further improve the question)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Code must be included directly into the question as minimal reproduicable code snippet (ctrl + m). If the link to your codepen chanegs or getting deleted or the content changes, the question would hold no further value to the community.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout)

Comment: No, don't worry, I made research before I posted the question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more rows like this:

```css
grid-template: ".   two   ." 1fr
               "one two  three" 1fr
               "one four three" 1fr
               ".   four  ." 1fr / 
               1fr  1fr  1fr;
```

With the appropriate `grid-area` on children.

Here is the snippet (I have also added a `height: 90%;` on children to make them fit the cells height but keeping the margin):

```css
#cards {
  padding: 0 7vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: ".   two  ." 1fr
                 "one two three" 1fr
                 "one four three" 1fr
                 ".   four  ." 1fr / 
                 1fr  1fr  1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card:nth-child(1){
  grid-area: one;
}
.card:nth-child(2){
  grid-area: two;
}
.card:nth-child(3){
  grid-area: three;
}
.card:nth-child(4){
  grid-area: four;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px -15px hsl(215, 49%, 82%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 3</h2>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 4</h2>
      <p>I built this two line paragraph oh yes I really want it to be two lines or yes finally.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I had tried many units and when % worked, I just used it

```css
#cards {
  padding: 0 7vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card:nth-child(1),
.card:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px -15px hsl(215, 49%, 82%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90%;
}

.card:nth-child(1), .card:nth-child(3) {
  height: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 3</h2>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">Item 4</h2>
      <p>I built this two line paragraph oh yes I really want it to be two lines or yes finally.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```