# Is there any way to break every word if one does it?

Tags: html, css

I've got an unusual problem with breaking words in HTML. The problem is inside the grid which is nested inside another one because every element has got its own height and width. I want to have got the same measurements for every `span` element.

Example:

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}
div > span{
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
span:nth-child(1){
  background-color: red;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
span:nth-child(3){
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <span class="title">Behind Her Eyes</span>
      <span class="rate">62%</span>
      <span class="main-character">Simona Brown</span>
     </div>
    <div>
      <span class="title">White Lines</span>
      <span class="rate">68%</span>
      <span class="main-character"> Laura Haddock</span>
     </div>
    <div>
      <span class="title">You</span>
      <span class="rate">87%</span>
      <span class="main-character">Penn Badgley</span>
     </div>
</body>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

EDIT: As you can see words can get the different lengths. `Behind Her Eyes` is longer and breaks differently than others, that's why columns are not similar and I want them to have got the same length.

Comment: Words in spans can vary in length, but if one line advances to the next line, the others will

Comment: Let me edit the question then

Comment: @connexo check it now

Comment: *that's why columns are not similar and I want them to have got the same length* I still don't understand what you expect instead of what it showing. CSS does not have `length`. It has `width` and `height`, and for both, all three columns are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` instead to get your desired result if I understood it correctly.

```css
body{
  display: flex;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
div > span {
  text-align: center;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span:nth-child(1){
  background-color: red;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
span:nth-child(3){
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasoihsidohfifpfpsdhfpofdsfsdgsdgsdgsdg</span>
      <span>bbbbbbb</span>
      <span>cccccc</span>
     </div>
    <div>
      <span>aaaaaaaa</span>
      <span>bbbbbbb</span>
      <span>cccccc</span>
     </div>
    <div>
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
      <span>bbbbbbb</span>
      <span>cccccc</span>
     </div>
</body>
```

If you want to have same length for both column and rows, then you can use   `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` using `display:grid` as mentioned here: [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout)

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
div > span{
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
span:nth-child(1){
  background-color: red;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
span:nth-child(3){
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaasoihsidohfifpfpsdhfpofdsfsdgsdgsdgsdg</span>
      <span>bbbbbbb</span>
      <span>cccccc</span>
     </div>
    <div>
      <span>aaaaaaaa</span>
      <span>bbbbbbb</span>
      <span>cccccc</span>
     </div>
    <div>
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
      <span>bbbbbbb</span>
      <span>cccccc</span>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want the columns to have got the same length for every element :/

Comment: `flex-grow: 1;` would fix that issue in that case, I've updated my answer.