# How do I set the height of a div to be the same as another div (which has a variable height) with Tailwind in a Nuxt application?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I have a grid with 3 columns. I want `item B` to be the same height as `item A` but `Item A` hasn't got a fixed height (depending on the content). I am using TailwindCSS in a Nuxt app. The `margin mb-4` doesn't seem to be applied for `Item B`. How do I do that ??

[image]

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3"/>
  <div class="mb-4">Item A</div>
  <div class="mb-4">Item A</div>
  <div class="mb-4 h-full">Item B</div>     
</div>
```

Comment: With a quick Google search, you can find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout Then setting `auto-rows-auto` in the parent should do it: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-rows

Comment: Thank you for that. But I don't want all the rows the same height, I only want the item A to impose the height to Item B. Item B being a list you can scroll down, if I don't impose a height to that element it will be very long. I think I might need to write a javascript function which output the height of Item A and use it to determine the height of Item B.