# Grid item content "jumps" when opened

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple arrangement like this. When I include `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` and open the `details` element, instead of opening downwards, it "jumps" in its place. This does not have if I set `grid-template-rows: auto`. But if I were to need set it explicitly, how to remove this "jumping" so that the element would still open normally?

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2px 2px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
  <details>
    <summary>Jumpy summary</summary>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1.</li>
      <li>Line 2.</li>
      <li>Line 3.</li>
      <li>Line 4.</li>
      <li>Line 5.</li>
      <li>Line 6.</li>
      <li>Line 7.</li>
      <li>Line 8.</li>
      <li>Line 9.</li>
      <li>Line 10.</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` you're setting two rows to be equal height.

So when the "Jumpy summary" section is collapsed, it's height is equal to the Paragraph item.

But when the section is expanded, the Paragraph item expands to meet the height of its sibling. That shifts the Jumpy summary half way down the screen.

The behavior is explained in detail here: [Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Use `grid-template-rows: auto auto` instead.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 2px 2px;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
  <details>
    <summary>Jumpy summary</summary>
    <ul>
      <li>Line 1.</li>
      <li>Line 2.</li>
      <li>Line 3.</li>
      <li>Line 4.</li>
      <li>Line 5.</li>
      <li>Line 6.</li>
      <li>Line 7.</li>
      <li>Line 8.</li>
      <li>Line 9.</li>
      <li>Line 10.</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</main>
```