# Make columns same height when stacked on top of each other Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to make columns the same height even when they turn into rows on mobile?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red">hi</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ullamcorper odio a maximus ultrices. Sed vitae pellentesque mi. Aenean sit amet eleifend augue. Donec lobortis lacinia nibh, nec scelerisque turpis scelerisque a. Maecenas id aliquam ante. Sed nec ornare sem. In nec fermentum odio.
      </div>
    </div>
```

On a smaller screen, the columns would stack on top of each other. The one with text would be long.. but the empty one would disappear. How to I make them the same height?

Answer (score 1):

Add following JS code:

```js
if (window.screen.width <= 600) {
  const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".col-sm-6")

  const maxHeight = Math.max(columns[0].offsetHeight, columns[1].offsetHeight)

  columns.forEach(column => { column.style.height = `${maxHeight}px` })
}
```

Comment: So it’s not possible with CSS then? I thought one of the more modern properties like flexbox might offer a solution to this. But I also wasn’t able to find anything any working example

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it is possible with CSS, when `flex-direction` is `column`. That's why I suggested a more dynamic way with JS.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer u to use `media queries` :D

so 1st give a same class to both of them like the following below:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="sm-same-height col-sm-6" style="background-color:red">hi</div>
      <div class="sm-same-height col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ullamcorper odio a maximus ultrices. Sed vitae pellentesque mi. Aenean sit amet eleifend augue. Donec lobortis lacinia nibh, nec scelerisque turpis scelerisque a. Maecenas id aliquam ante. Sed nec ornare sem. In nec fermentum odio.
      </div>
    </div>
```

and 2nd add some of the CSS like that :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 375px) {
  .sm-same-height{
    height:125px; 
   }
 }
```

`(min-width: 375px)` is the responsive size of mobile phone :)

hope it hepls you <3

Comment: Thanks but this requires we know the height of content when you can make the screen any size.. which is a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the answer already written on Stack Overflow. If you want to use CSS and don't know the height of the longest container, you can use CSS grid layout.

[Equal height rows in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout)

Then I used this only on smaller screens

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
.row{
    display: grid !important;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
}
```

Comment: I do not know if I would combine `flexbox` and `grid` in your case. Using the class `col-sm-6`, you are under the media query `@media (min-width: 576px)`.