# How do I make content of different heights the same height in css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm creating a vertical single column listing.
Some of the text is 200 characters long and some is 1 character. And list width changes dynamically.

**How do I dynamically make each the same height?**

all conditions are below.

- no stretch. If there are margins with only two pieces, pack them on top.
- Must be scrollable if it extends beyond the screen.
- Match height to largest cell.

There are ways to make the height uniformly 200px, but I don't like it because it is not dynamic. When we set each height to 200px, the layout will be broken if we change the width of the list.

this is now.
As you can see, the height of red and blue are different. I want these to be the same.

```
.grid {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/msickpaler/Lndmjc46/17/

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example using the "Code snippet" tool?

Comment: yes. plz wait a minutes

Comment: So do I get this right: You want the grid item height to be defined by the highest grid item and all other grid items should grow so that they match that height?

Comment: yes! Thanks for the clear summary. and added details. sry for late

Answer (score 1):

Change the grid-template-rows to

```
grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
```

Which should automatically make them all the height of the highest item.

Answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout)

Comment: I added the property you answered and commented out the height property and it worked. However, if I added `height: 100vh;` and `overflow: scroll;` the height depends on the respective content. Do you have any good ideas?
this is fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/msickpaler/twconkr5/2/

Comment: I think grid-auto-rows only works when there is infinite space for it to expand the grid into, ie. no fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.grid {
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: scroll;
   display: grid;
   /* grid-template-rows: 100px 100px; */
   grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.long-text {
   background-color: red;
}

.short-text {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried with a lot of childs. Looks good, but oddly enough, nothing has changed in the height of the area protruding from the screen.