# Tailwind cards of same height across multiple rows

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a grid of cards for service requests. I have not been able to get all cards to simply have the same height. It works fine for the row the largest item is at but the next row height is smaller. How do I have them all the same height?

Code:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/ACR2zkFOeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch `auto-rows-max` with `auto-rows-fr`. You can read more about the `fr` unit [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit). Here's a StackOverflow answer about a similar scenario with a comprehensive explanation of why it works: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout). `auto-rows-fr` is the same as `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` as you can see in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-rows).

[Tailwind-play with a working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/wmAx77RlUs).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
  <div class="h-96"></div>
  <div class="h-96"></div>
  <div class="h-96"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code isn't responsive, I wouldn't recommend setting static heights. For example, what will happen when the text overflows `h-96`?

Comment: Can use overflow-auto class if text overflows. But, you are right, it is not a good practice to use fixed height without necessity.