# Equal height for rows of CSS Grid or Flexbox with non-infinite height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout) works and explains why it works for **infinite height** CSS grid. In my case, the height is limited (which could be `100vh` or due to `flex-grow` but it's not infinite).

Let's say I have a certain space for a grid (decided by a flex box which is the remaining space of whatever remaining of the screen). I want it to be divided into two equal rows. The top one should be an `img` with `object-fit: scale-down` that take up all 50% height and at most 100% width and the bottom row should be some random text. Problem is, when the `img` is bigger, it takes up additional space (see example below).

Is it possible to divide a CSS grid or flex box (or any kind of display) into two strictly equal rows?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  
  padding: 1rem;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
  <div class="content">Another content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `img` inside a `div` and set the `img` `position: absolute`, the setting seems to work OK.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid > .img-container {
  position:relative;
  background:pink;
}

img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">Another content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's one good workaround though IMO it's a bit hacky. But it works! And this approach works when the amount of rows is not known.

Comment: Yes, always a bit uncomfortable if add to the DOM to get round a styling problem, but was the best I could come up with at the moment, and given my laptop has collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, I used a flexbox container with the class `.flex` to split a space into two equal rows. The top row holds an image with `object-fit: scale-down`, while the bottom row contains text. To prevent the image from affecting the row's height, I set `flex-grow: 1` and a fixed `height: 50%` for the image. The text row's height is also set to `50%` with `flex-grow: 1`. This layout maintains equal row heights even when the image is larger.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.flex {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
  <div class="content">Another content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, explaining your answers in a bit more detail (even through code comments) can help OP and other users figure out what went wrong and learn from their mistakes

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about setting it to 50%. However in your example, it's not correct. If you inspect the result, the two elements don't have the same height. EDIT: removing `gap` would work though I don't know why.

Comment: Eliminating the `gap` would result in an unappealing appearance. I introduced a `20px` `gap` to enhance its visual appeal slightly. If this doesn't suit your preferences, I can remove the `gap` as per your preference.