# How can I use display:grid so if there is space between elements vertically, the element always moves up and fills the space?

Tags: html, css

So basically I am doing a 2 colunm grid but some of the elements have higher height then the other leaving a big gap vertically. Is there a way to aling it so it fills that space. The idea is to keep the grid, and I did try to do a span 2 but its too big, I want it to be like 1.33 span but obviously is not possible since it has to be whole numbers. Is there something on display:grid property that I am missing so it automatically moves up so there is not a big gap between elements vertically?

[image]

So far this is what I have on my CSS:

```
.container-gpt {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 77%;
    margin-inline: auto;

}


.bubble h3, .learn-more a, .bubble p {
    color: white !important;
    margin:0px !important;
}
.bubble {
    background-color: #051B26;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 17rem;
}

.bubble:hover {
    background-color: #136A64; /* Different color on hover */
}

.bubble img {
    width: auto;
    height: 122px;
}

.learn-more {
    color: #051B26;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.learn-more {
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
}
.learn-more:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.bubble:first-child {
    min-height: 22.65rem;
}
.bubble:not(:first-child) {
    height: 17rem; /* Set fixed height for bubbles other than the first */
}
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="container-gpt">
<div  id="basecamp" class="bubble item1  greenhover">

  <img src="/images/ec79b373-4939-48e6-a455-6e31314c03b6/Icon_Basecamp_Large.png" alt="Basecamp" data-image="6tlj5gbrco2p">
    <h3>Basecamp</h3>
    <p>View Your Basics</p>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>
</div>


<div id="accountmng" class="bubble item2 greenhover ">
    <img src="/images/c938ee00-0f29-4341-bfce-a9902efd3c26/Icon_AccountsManagement_Small.png" alt="Accounts Management" data-image="sq10hlnbpmuu">
    <span class="force-white">Progress: 30%</span>
    <h3>Accounts Management</h3>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>

</div>

<div  id="cashflow" class="bubble  item3 greenhover">

    <img src="/images/c938ee00-0f29-4341-bfce-a9902efd3c26/Icon_AccountsManagement_Small.png" alt="Accounts Management" data-image="sq10hlnbpmuu">
    <h3>Basecamp</h3>
    <p>View Your Basics</p>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>
</div>


<div id="cashmg" class="bubble item4 greenhover ">
    <img src="/images/c938ee00-0f29-4341-bfce-a9902efd3c26/Icon_AccountsManagement_Small.png" alt="Accounts Management" data-image="sq10hlnbpmuu">
    <span class="force-white">Progress: 30%</span>
    <h3>Accounts Management</h3>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502844/19090048. Dont' apply unnecessary height property and `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove grid and use

```
.container{
    columns: 2;
} 
.item{ 
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Where container is the div outside all of your cards and item is your card

You will get something like this:

https://ayushm.vercel.app/#projects

Comment: omg, I am so behind on CSS. Thank you.

Comment: Not an issue, everyone starts here. Wish you all the very best!

Answer (score 0):

The space occurs because you are explicitly applying `height` to each element `.bubble`. If you remove that rule every thing align equally.

```css
.container-gpt {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 77%;
    margin-inline: auto;

}


.bubble h3, .learn-more a, .bubble p {
    color: white !important;
    margin:0px !important;
}
.bubble {
    background-color: #051B26;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*max-height: 17rem; this also */
}

.bubble:hover {
    background-color: #136A64; /* Different color on hover */
}

.bubble img {
    width: auto;
    height: 122px;
}

.learn-more {
    color: #051B26;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.learn-more {
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
}
.learn-more:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.bubble:first-child {
    min-height: 22.65rem;
}
/*.bubble:not(:first-child) { renmove this and allow grid to auto allocate
    height: 17rem; 
}*/
```

```html
<div class="container-gpt">
<div  id="basecamp" class="bubble item1  greenhover">

  <img src="/images/ec79b373-4939-48e6-a455-6e31314c03b6/Icon_Basecamp_Large.png" alt="Basecamp" data-image="6tlj5gbrco2p">
    <h3>Basecamp</h3>
    <p>View Your Basics</p>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>
</div>


<div id="accountmng" class="bubble item2 greenhover ">
    <img src="/images/c938ee00-0f29-4341-bfce-a9902efd3c26/Icon_AccountsManagement_Small.png" alt="Accounts Management" data-image="sq10hlnbpmuu">
    <span class="force-white">Progress: 30%</span>
    <h3>Accounts Management</h3>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>

</div>

<div  id="cashflow" class="bubble  item3 greenhover">

    <img src="/images/c938ee00-0f29-4341-bfce-a9902efd3c26/Icon_AccountsManagement_Small.png" alt="Accounts Management" data-image="sq10hlnbpmuu">
    <h3>Basecamp</h3>
    <p>View Your Basics</p>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>
</div>


<div id="cashmg" class="bubble item4 greenhover ">
    <img src="/images/c938ee00-0f29-4341-bfce-a9902efd3c26/Icon_AccountsManagement_Small.png" alt="Accounts Management" data-image="sq10hlnbpmuu">
    <span class="force-white">Progress: 30%</span>
    <h3>Accounts Management</h3>
    <a href="#" class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</a>

</div>
```