Making all div to follow the height of the tallest div
I want to achieve that all the div that is in table values should be of the same height in short the height of all the div should be of the same height inside the table values
I have tried some solutions but didn't work for me.
As shown in the image the first line item is the tallest so all the other have the height of the tallest one



.section-4 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
}

.section-4 .table .table-header {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.section-4 .table .sr_no,
.section-4 .table .unit {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 3%;
}

.section-4 .table .unit {
  width: 5%;
}

.section-4 .table .qty {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 8.3%;
}

.section-4 .table .des_of_goods {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 49%;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .des_of_goods .content {
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.section-4 .table .rate,
.section-4 .table .disc,
.section-4 .table .tax-amt,
.section-4 .table .disc-amt {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 8.75%;
}

.section-4 .table .tax-amt {
  border-right: 0;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: row wrap; */
  /* align-items: stretch; */
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  /* height: 100%; */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .add-info,
.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .order-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .add-info {
  /* margin-top: 5px; */
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .des_of_goods .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .add-info p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<section class="section-4">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="sr_no">
        <p><strong>SR No.</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="des_of_goods">
        <p><strong>Description of Goods</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="qty">
        <p><strong>Qty</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="unit">
        <p><strong>Unit</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="rate">
        <p><strong>Rate</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="disc">
        <p><strong>Disc. %</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="disc-amt">
        <p><strong>Discount Amount</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tax-amt">
        <p><strong>Taxable Amount</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-values">
      <div class="table-cell sr_no text-center">
        <p><strong>2</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell des_of_goods">
        <div class="content">
          <p><strong>TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE</strong></p>
          <div class="add-info">
            <p>HSN : 6004100 </p>
            <p>Width: 60 ( inch ) </p>
            <p>Buyer Ref: VO240052 </p>
          </div>
          <div class="order-info">
            <p>Order no: SRFSO2425- 00429 </p>
            <p>Challan/Packing no: SRFSD2425- 03410</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell qty text-center">
        <p>21,232.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell unit text-center">
        <p>Mtr.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell rate text-center">
        <p>9,610.80</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell disc text-center">
        <p>100.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell disc-amt text-center">
        <p>10,000.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell tax-amt text-center">
        <p>30,77,002.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-values">
      <div class="table-cell sr_no text-center">
        <p><strong>2</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell des_of_goods">
        <div class="content">
          <p><strong>TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE</strong></p>
          <div class="add-info">
            <p>HSN : 6004100 </p>
            <p>Width: 60 ( inch ) </p>
            <p>Buyer Ref: VO240052 </p>
          </div>
          <div class="order-info">
            <p>Order no: SRFSO2425- 00429 </p>
            <p>Challan/Packing no: SRFSD2425- 03410</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell qty text-center">
        <p>21,232.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell unit text-center">
        <p>Mtr.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell rate text-center">
        <p>9,610.80</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell disc text-center">
        <p>100.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell disc-amt text-center">
        <p>10,000.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell tax-amt text-center">
        <p>30,77,002.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-values">
      <div class="table-cell sr_no text-center">
        <p><strong>2</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell des_of_goods">
        <div class="content">
          <p><strong>TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE</strong></p>
          <div class="add-info">
            <p>HSN : 6004100 </p>
            <p>Width: 60 ( inch ) </p>
            <p>Buyer Ref: VO240052 </p>
          </div>
          <div class="order-info">
            <p>Order no: SRFSO2425- 00429 </p>
            <p>Challan/Packing no: SRFSD2425- 03410</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell qty text-center">
        <p>21,232.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell unit text-center">
        <p>Mtr.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell rate text-center">
        <p>9,610.80</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell disc text-center">
        <p>100.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell disc-amt text-center">
        <p>10,000.00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell tax-amt text-center">
        <p>30,77,002.00</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout

For your example - which is not an actual table and therefore suffers from columns not having the right width - you could use grid with grid-auto-rows: 1fr;


.container {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;

}

.container div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
<div class="container">
  <div>
    row 1
  </div>
  <div>
    row 2
  </div>
  <div>
    row 3.1<br>row 3.2<br>row 3.3
  </div>
</div>



This is how it would look like if applied to your setup: the only thing changed for HTML is that all your table-values are wrapped in one  div. (It still suffers from your original problem that the columns of the different rows don't line up correctly if the window is too small, but that can only be solved if you use something different then flex).


/* CSS to make rows equal height */
.section-4 .table-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}


/* all of your original code */
.section-4 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
}

.section-4 .table .table-header {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.section-4 .table .sr_no,
.section-4 .table .unit {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 3%;
}

.section-4 .table .unit {
  width: 5%;
}

.section-4 .table .qty {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 8.3%;
}

.section-4 .table .des_of_goods {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 49%;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .des_of_goods .content {
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.section-4 .table .rate,
.section-4 .table .disc,
.section-4 .table .tax-amt,
.section-4 .table .disc-amt {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 8.75%;
}

.section-4 .table .tax-amt {
  border-right: 0;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: row wrap; */
  /* align-items: stretch; */
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  /* height: 100%; */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .add-info,
.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .order-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .add-info {
  /* margin-top: 5px; */
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .des_of_goods .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.section-4 .table .table-values .table-cell .add-info p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<section class="section-4">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div class="sr_no">
        <p><strong>SR No.</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="des_of_goods">
        <p><strong>Description of Goods</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="qty">
        <p><strong>Qty</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="unit">
        <p><strong>Unit</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="rate">
        <p><strong>Rate</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="disc">
        <p><strong>Disc. %</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="disc-amt">
        <p><strong>Discount Amount</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tax-amt">
        <p><strong>Taxable Amount</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- div that wraps around all your  table-values -->
    <div class="table-body">
      <div class="table-values">
        <div class="table-cell sr_no text-center">
          <p><strong>2</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell des_of_goods">
          <div class="content">
            <p><strong>TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE</strong></p>
            <div class="add-info">
              <p>HSN : 6004100 </p>
              <p>Width: 60 ( inch ) </p>
              <p>Buyer Ref: VO240052 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="order-info">
              <p>Order no: SRFSO2425- 00429 </p>
              <p>Challan/Packing no: SRFSD2425- 03410</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell qty text-center">
          <p>21,232.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell unit text-center">
          <p>Mtr.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell rate text-center">
          <p>9,610.80</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell disc text-center">
          <p>100.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell disc-amt text-center">
          <p>10,000.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell tax-amt text-center">
          <p>30,77,002.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-values">
        <div class="table-cell sr_no text-center">
          <p><strong>2</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell des_of_goods">
          <div class="content">
            <p><strong>TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE</strong></p>
            <div class="add-info">
              <p>HSN : 6004100 </p>
              <p>Width: 60 ( inch ) </p>
              <p>Buyer Ref: VO240052 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="order-info">
              <p>Order no: SRFSO2425- 00429 </p>
              <p>Challan/Packing no: SRFSD2425- 03410</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell qty text-center">
          <p>21,232.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell unit text-center">
          <p>Mtr.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell rate text-center">
          <p>9,610.80</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell disc text-center">
          <p>100.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell disc-amt text-center">
          <p>10,000.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell tax-amt text-center">
          <p>30,77,002.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-values">
        <div class="table-cell sr_no text-center">
          <p><strong>2</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell des_of_goods">
          <div class="content">
            <p><strong>TR45A/NS/5aSSHJLJ4- I : TR-45A : HEATSET : HEAT
                  SET R-45A HEATSET bLUE</strong></p>
            <div class="add-info">
              <p>HSN : 6004100 </p>
              <p>Width: 60 ( inch ) </p>
              <p>Buyer Ref: VO240052 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="order-info">
              <p>Order no: SRFSO2425- 00429 </p>
              <p>Challan/Packing no: SRFSD2425- 03410</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell qty text-center">
          <p>21,232.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell unit text-center">
          <p>Mtr.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell rate text-center">
          <p>9,610.80</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell disc text-center">
          <p>100.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell disc-amt text-center">
          <p>10,000.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell tax-amt text-center">
          <p>30,77,002.00</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



If you can use subgrid, you could use table, which would also have semantic meaning or any HTML structure you want like yours. You might need to adapt the CSS a bit; right now is a of a proof of concept and probably does not fully reflect what you need:


table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr max-content;
}

tbody,
thead,
tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Row 1-1</td>
      <td>Row 1-2</td>
      <td>Row 1-3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Row 2-1</td>
      <td>Row 2-2</td>
      <td>Row 2-3.1<br>Row 2-3.2<br>Row 2-3.3<br>Row 2-3.4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




anything with flexbox i can do?

@AtulSharma Why do you want to use flex for the rows?

i am as u can see in my provided code i am doing this using flex the whole time rn i can't bear major change and i want to make a fixed width invoice that's why i am using flex for more ease. so please suggest me some idea using flex. thanks

and i want to make a fixed width invoice ok, but what is the problem of just using the first suggestion I made just for the row part, so that all rows have the same height, and inside of the rows continue to use flex?

yes will continue with flex, please suggest me with that. i have provided the HTML and CSS for it please suggest changes on it

@AtulSharma It is not possible with just flexbox because flexbox doesn't work that way. Grids do allow you to define things based on their sizing.

@t.niese thankyou, it is working as expected. thanks for your time
