Css subgrid align elements across multiple rows
I'm trying to create a grid of cards where elements (title, content, button) align perfectly across ALL cards, even across different rows. While CSS subgrid works within a single row, I can't get elements to align across multiple rows.
An example:

A 3x3 grid of cards

Each card has 3 elements: title, content, and button

All content sections should align and expand based on the largest content


.Grid_Container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.Grid_Item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

<div className="Grid_Container">
  <div className="Grid_Item">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Content</p>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  {/* Repeated for 9 cards */}
</div>


As you can see on the image, the alignment of the items using CSS subgrid is working fine PER row. However, I would like to align it based on all the rows meaning:
If any card has:

A tall title: all titles in all cards should expand to the tallest title

Tall content: all content sections should expand to the tallest section

A tall button: all button sections should expand to the tallest button.


So I can create cards that have exactly the same layout.

Not possible with CSS. You can make the rows the same height but that's not how subgrid works. It works in one direction only, it can't align heights in different rows. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout

grid-auto-rows: 1fr on the container?

@tacoshy That will make the card rows the same height but not equalise heights of the card contents AFAIK.

@Paulie_D of course not, but if you have the same button and headline height, the content height will automatically be at the same height as well.

True but that's not the requirement here. It's clear that the card content heights differ from one card to another.

You can get the look with CSS, but I think you'll end up with needing some JS to ensure the container's actual size is right in the end.
Here's a simple example. First get the look you want for each card by putting them all on the same row.As you have found, this can get the right heights for each of the internal elements.
Then translate the cards to where you want to see them.


<style>
  .Grid_Container {
    display: grid;
    width: 300vw;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .Grid_Container>div:nth-child(4),
  .Grid_Container>div:nth-child(5),
  .Grid_Container>div:nth-child(6) {
    transform: translate(calc(-300% - 30px), 100%);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .Grid_Container>div:nth-child(7),
  .Grid_Container>div:nth-child(8),
  .Grid_Container>div:nth-child(9) {
    transform: translate(calc(-600% - 60px), 200%);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .Grid_Item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: subgrid;
    grid-row: span 3;
  }
</style>
<div class="Grid_Container">
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title<br>with 2 lines</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content<br>with 3 lines<br>last line</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button<br>with 2 lines</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Grid_Item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>



