# CSS flex-grow height unequal, flex-basis not fixing

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to get the heights of these items to be the same no matter how much content is inside, but I keep getting the content to cause uneven heights.

[image]

Code in a simplified version of ReactJS Code:

```
<div className='flex flex-column height-100-percent'> //Page Area
     <div className='flex justify-between'>
        Words...
     </div>
     <div className='flex flex-grow flex-wrap'> // Div with days 
        {<div className='width-25-percent'>
             <Scheduler className='width-160-pixel'... /> 
        </div>} TIMES SEVEN....
     </div>
 </div>
```

The **classNames should be self-explanatory**. I tried to use `flex-basis` of `0`, `100%`, and `auto` with no luck. I also tried `flex: 1` with no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004926/equal-height-rows-in-a-flex-container possible duplicate.

Comment: I answered it using a method they didn't suggest in the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468531/8430249 , thank you for comments!