# Same height for flex items in the flex-direction column flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to have flex items within a flex container with `flex-direction: column` have the same height, using CSS only?

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
 <div class="flex-item">
   <!-- other html elements with image, links, button etc. -->
 </div>
 <!-- ... -->
 <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hzxa9v54/

Comment: Yes. Just use `height`. That's what it's for.

Comment: I believe giving each child `flex: 1;` will keep all heights equal when using `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb height value will not work, as flex items have different content

Comment: Why do they need to be the same height if they're in a column?

Comment: you mean in a wrapping situation?

Comment: sorry guys, fiddle added. the problem is that the content is different and I need to make each flex-item to have a height as largest item has

Comment: @mcmxc You need a script to do that.

Comment: @LGSon yeah, seems like so.. I know we can do that for flex row without js (to adjust the heights) but not for the column I believe

Comment: Equal height flex items in a column is not natively possible with flexbox. However, it's simple and easy with CSS Grid. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hzxa9v54/8/) | [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276)

Comment: @philr That edit/update only work if you set a height on the parent, which OP doesn't have/want.

Comment: @Michael_B Since Grid appears to adjust even after an image load, I suggest you post that as a script free answer :)

Comment: @LGSon, if OP is open to a Grid solution, the question should be amended and I'll post my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a script to solve that using Flexbox, here done using jQuery.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzxa9v54/2/)

Stack snippet

```js
(function ($) {

  // preload object array to gain performance
  var $items = $('.item')
  
  // run at resize
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $.fn.setHeight(0);   
  });  

  $.fn.setHeight = function(height) {

    // reset to auto or else we can't check height
    $($items).css({ 'height': 'auto' });
    
    // get highest value
    $($items).each(function(i, obj) {    
      height = Math.max(height, $(obj).outerHeight()) 
    });

    // set the height
    $($items).css({ 'height': height + 'px' });    
  }

  // run at load
  $.fn.setHeight(0);
  
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    come content 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    come content 2
    come content 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    come content 4
    come content 5
    come content 6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    come content 7
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Update based on a comment, where e.g. also loading images needs to be taken into account.

Here is an updated version of the script, that adjust after image loads.

```js
(function ($) {

  // preload object array to gain performance
  var $items = $('.item')
  
  // run at resize
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $.fn.setHeight(0);   
  });  

  $.fn.setHeight = function(height) {

    // reset to auto or else we can't check height
    $($items).css({ 'height': 'auto' });
    
    // get highest value
    $($items).each(function(i, obj) {    
      height = Math.max(height, $(obj).outerHeight()) 
    });

    // set the height
    $($items).css({ 'height': height + 'px' });    
  }

  function imageLoaded() {
    $.fn.setHeight(0);
  }
  
  var images = $('.item img');
  if (images) {
    images.each(function() {
      if( this.complete ) {
        imageLoaded.call( this );
      } else {
        $(this).one('load', imageLoaded);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // run at load
    $.fn.setHeight(0);
  }

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    come content 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100/f00" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    come content 4
    come content 5
    come content 6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    come content 7
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one problem - if there is an image inside, I need to wait until all of them fully loaded.. is there any way to do that, without including any libraries?

Comment: @mcmxc Let me know if the suggested solution for images work, and I will add it to my answer.

Comment: thanks mate, works great. Script does all the work, not even necessary to use flex box layout. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: using your fiddle, i made slight modifications and used `flex: 1 1 100%;` on the flex children and it appears to be working.

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hzxa9v54/4/

Comment: That's not entirely true : you need to also give them the same flex-basis, and same flex-shrink. Or is it a shortcut for `flex: 1 1 auto;` ?

Comment: @trichetriche it is actually a shortcut for `flex: 1 1 0;` which is pretty much equivalent to `flex: 1 1 auto;` meaning there is no minimum height (in this case) for the div

Comment: @trichetriche no problem

Comment: @trichetriche and philr, `flex: 1 1 0` is far from  equivalent to `flex: 1 1 auto`, where in the latter, the content is taken into account before the flex growth is calculated

Comment: Sure @LGSon, but I was asking if this was a shortcut, and he said precisely that it is a shortcut for `1 1 0`, so it answered my question.

Comment: @LGSon you're right, my bad `flex-basis: 0;` and `flex-basis: auto;` are not the same

Comment: Furthermore, as the parent doesn't have a set height to fill, and as the content might differ in size, this can't be done w/o script.

Comment: @philr the problem is that the content is different and I need to make each flex-item to have a height as largest item has. fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hzxa9v54/

Comment: @mcmxc in that case, LGSon is correct. You need a script