# flex-direction: row - children of same height

Tags: css, flexbox

How is it possible to get the `.child`s to all have the same height. `height: 100%` is not working an neither is `flex-grow: 1`. What is the recommended approach for this using flexbox?

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 800px;
}

.child {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Short Text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Long Text: Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Short Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `align-items: center;`

Comment: May be you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004926/equal-height-rows-in-a-flex-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 800px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Short Text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Long Text: Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Short Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `align-items:center` from the parent and add flex properties to the children for their content alignment.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 800px;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Short Text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Long Text: Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Short Text
  </div>
</div>
```