# jQuery/Vanilla JS - parse string to HTML and get it own height

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to parse many string values (which are probably HTML) to HTML and then, get it own height (as HTML node). I don't want to create real node inside my real HTML, probably there is a way to create fake one and get it height?

Example:

```
const arrOfHtml = ["<div>Test</div>", "<div><h2>Test2></h2></div><div><p>Im not ok</p></div>"];
arrOfHtml.forEach(el => {
  console.log($(el).height())
})
```

Comment: The problem is that the browser doesn't know exactly what the height is until the element is added to the DOM and layout decisions are made.

Comment: Any way to fake it? I understand that I can just add and delete it, but performance of my app will be dead.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do by getting the height like this?

Comment: Nope, I don't think you can fake it, the results will likely depend on any CSS that gets applied to any of these elements.

Comment: @epascarello, Im trying to set row height of my table component, which will depends on HTML elements inside a row. So for example if HTML element hight will be higher of default row height, I will increase it.

Comment: *I'm trying to set row height of my table component, which will depends on HTML elements inside a row.* (which seems different from the asked question) - consider using css flex: `justify-content: stretch;` or `display:grid`.   Not quite the same question, but some examples of justify-content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004926/equal-height-rows-in-a-flex-container

Comment: I will be happy to use it, but, Im using virtual table component of React.js. I need to specify height constantly (height = 32 etc.).

Comment: "*virtual table component of React.js*" - didn't see that in the question... please provide all relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy makes a great point in their comment.

If you want to get the height of an HTML node, you have to render it. You don't really have a choice, elements have to be added to the DOM. I've found that performance isn't usually an issue unless you have hundreds of elements.