# Flexbox Grid - Equal Height Columns

Tags: css, flexbox, flexboxgrid

I am using Flexbox Grid (http://flexboxgrid.com/) and I trying to make my columns equal height instead of having individual heights. Does anybody know how to do this as I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row middle-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="motability-bg">
        <img src="/img/new-car-template/motab-bg.jpg" alt="motability seat">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="motability-content-bg"></div>
      <div class="motability-content">
        <h1>Motability</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment my column with the `img` tag is larger than my content column. Any idea how I can set them equal?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: are you using bootstrap ? if yes then : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/

Comment: No I am using the link mentioned above: http://flexboxgrid.com/

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use the class `middle-xs` aside row

```
.middle-xs {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center
}
```

snippet below:

```css
/*! normalize.css v2.1.3 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}

[hidden],
template {
  display: none
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

a {
  background: 0 0
}

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: .67em 0
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 700
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sup {
  top: -.5em
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25em
}

img {
  border: 0
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}

figure {
  margin: 0
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
html input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #EEE;
  line-height: 1.4rem
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: Gibson, HelveticaNeue-Light, "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  color: #001A33
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 1rem 0
}

:focus {
  outline-color: transparent;
  outline-style: none
}

h2+p {
  margin: 0 0 2rem
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #007FFF;
  padding: 0 0 .2rem;
  font-weight: 700
}

a:hover {
  color: #007FFF
}

pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  margin: 1.6em 0;
  font-size: .875em;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  white-space: pre;
  word-wrap: normal
}

code {
  color: #007FFF
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column
}

.page-nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  padding: .5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0 0
}

.page {
  z-index: 0;
  background: #EEE
}

.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.page-section {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem
}

.page-features {
  width: 100%;
  background: #001a33;
  overflow: scroll
}

.menu-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: .75rem;
  right: .75rem;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .45rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  user-select: none
}

.menu-button:hover {
  border: 1px solid #007FFF;
  border-radius: 2px
}

.menu-button:active {
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}

.open {
  transform: translate3d(-15rem, 0, 0)
}

.menu-button-icon {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem
}

.hero {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 2px
}

.hero-headline {
  font-size: 3rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.hero-copy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-align: center
}

.slide-menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px
}

.menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  background: #001a33
}

.menu-header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3rem 3rem 0;
  color: #eee
}

.menu-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.menu-list-item {
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #007FFF;
  background: 0 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in
}

.menu-link {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  display: block;
  color: #007FFF;
  transition: color .2s ease-in
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: #3298ff;
  border-bottom: 0
}

.link-top {
  align-self: flex-end
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 11rem;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid #007FFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #007FFF;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  transition: background-color, .15s
}

.button:hover {
  background: #39F;
  border-color: #39F;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #007FFF
}

.button:active {
  background: #007FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #06C
}

.box,
.box-first,
.box-large,
.box-nested,
.box-row {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #007FFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}

.box-row {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}

.box-first {
  background: #06C;
  border-color: #007FFF
}

.box-nested {
  background: #036;
  border-color: #007FFF
}

.box-large {
  height: 8rem
}

.box-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .5rem
}

.page-footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 3rem
}

.tag {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400
}

.end {
  text-align: end
}

.invisible-xs {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden
}

.visible-xs {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible
}

@media only screen and (min-width:48rem) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px
  }
  .slide-menu {
    width: 25%
  }
  .open {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  .hero-headline {
    font-size: 6rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem
  }
  .hero-copy {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem
  }
  .box,
  .box-first,
  .box-large,
  .box-nested,
  .box-row {
    padding: 1rem
  }
  .invisible-md {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden
  }
  .visible-md {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible
  }
}

.container,
.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem
}

.row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -.5rem;
  margin-left: -.5rem
}

.row.reverse {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.col.reverse {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column-reverse
}

.col-xs,
.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-offset-1,
.col-xs-offset-10,
.col-xs-offset-11,
.col-xs-offset-12,
.col-xs-offset-2,
.col-xs-offset-3,
.col-xs-offset-4,
.col-xs-offset-5,
.col-xs-offset-6,
.col-xs-offset-7,
.col-xs-offset-8,
.col-xs-offset-9 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem
}

.col-xs {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  max-width: 100%
}

.col-xs-1 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 8.333%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.333%;
  flex-basis: 8.333%;
  max-width: 8.333%
}

.col-xs-2 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 16.667%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.667%;
  flex-basis: 16.667%;
  max-width: 16.667%
}

.col-xs-3 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 25%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  max-width: 25%
}

.col-xs-4 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 33.333%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.333%;
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%
}

.col-xs-5 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 41.667%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.667%;
  flex-basis: 41.667%;
  max-width: 41.667%
}

.col-xs-6 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 50%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%
}

.col-xs-7 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 58.333%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.333%;
  flex-basis: 58.333%;
  max-width: 58.333%
}

.col-xs-8 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 66.667%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.667%;
  flex-basis: 66.667%;
  max-width: 66.667%
}

.col-xs-9 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 75%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  max-width: 75%
}

.col-xs-10 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 83.333%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.333%;
  flex-basis: 83.333%;
  max-width: 83.333%
}

.col-xs-11 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 91.667%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.667%;
  flex-basis: 91.667%;
  max-width: 91.667%
}

.col-xs-12 {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}

.col-xs-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.333%
}

.col-xs-offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.667%
}

.col-xs-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%
}

.col-xs-offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.333%
}

.col-xs-offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.667%
}

.col-xs-offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%
}

.col-xs-offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.333%
}

.col-xs-offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.667%
}

.col-xs-offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%
}

.col-xs-offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.333%
}

.col-xs-offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.667%
}

.start-xs {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: start
}

.center-xs {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center
}

.end-xs {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: end
}

.top-xs {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start
}

.middle-xs {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center
}

.bottom-xs {
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-align: end;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.around-xs {
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around
}

.between-xs {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.first-xs {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
  -webkit-order: -1;
  -ms-flex-order: -1;
  order: -1
}

.last-xs {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1
}

@media only screen and (min-width:48em) {
  .container {
    width: 49rem
  }
  .col-sm,
  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-offset-1,
  .col-sm-offset-10,
  .col-sm-offset-11,
  .col-sm-offset-12,
  .col-sm-offset-2,
  .col-sm-offset-3,
  .col-sm-offset-4,
  .col-sm-offset-5,
  .col-sm-offset-6,
  .col-sm-offset-7,
  .col-sm-offset-8,
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem
  }
  .col-sm {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 8.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.333%;
    flex-basis: 8.333%;
    max-width: 8.333%
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 16.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.667%;
    flex-basis: 16.667%;
    max-width: 16.667%
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 25%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 33.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.333%;
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
    max-width: 33.333%
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 41.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.667%;
    flex-basis: 41.667%;
    max-width: 41.667%
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 50%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%
  }
  .col-sm-7 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 58.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.333%;
    flex-basis: 58.333%;
    max-width: 58.333%
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 66.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.667%;
    flex-basis: 66.667%;
    max-width: 66.667%
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 75%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 83.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.333%;
    flex-basis: 83.333%;
    max-width: 83.333%
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 91.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.667%;
    flex-basis: 91.667%;
    max-width: 91.667%
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.333%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.667%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.333%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.667%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.333%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.667%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.333%
  }
  .col-sm-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.667%
  }
  .start-sm {
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: start
  }
  .center-sm {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center
  }
  .end-sm {
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: end
  }
  .top-sm {
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start
  }
  .middle-sm {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
  }
  .bottom-sm {
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end
  }
  .around-sm {
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around
  }
  .between-sm {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between
  }
  .first-sm {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
    -webkit-order: -1;
    -ms-flex-order: -1;
    order: -1
  }
  .last-sm {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:64em) {
  .container {
    width: 65rem
  }
  .col-md,
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11,
  .col-md-12,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-offset-1,
  .col-md-offset-10,
  .col-md-offset-11,
  .col-md-offset-12,
  .col-md-offset-2,
  .col-md-offset-3,
  .col-md-offset-4,
  .col-md-offset-5,
  .col-md-offset-6,
  .col-md-offset-7,
  .col-md-offset-8,
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem
  }
  .col-md {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 8.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 8.333%;
    flex-basis: 8.333%;
    max-width: 8.333%
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 16.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16.667%;
    flex-basis: 16.667%;
    max-width: 16.667%
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 25%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 25%
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 33.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.333%;
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
    max-width: 33.333%
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 41.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 41.667%;
    flex-basis: 41.667%;
    max-width: 41.667%
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 50%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 50%;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 58.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 58.333%;
    flex-basis: 58.333%;
    max-width: 58.333%
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 66.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 66.667%;
    flex-basis: 66.667%;
    max-width: 66.667%
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 75%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 75%;
    flex-basis: 75%;
    max-width: 75%
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 83.333%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 83.333%;
    flex-basis: 83.333%;
    max-width: 83.333%
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 91.667%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 91.667%;
    flex-basis: 91.667%;
    max-width: 91.667%
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.333%
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.667%
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.333%
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.667%
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.333%
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.667%
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.333%
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.667%
  }
  .start-md {
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: start
  }
  .center-md {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center
  }
  .end-md {
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: end
  }
  .top-md {
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start
  }
  .middle-md {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
  }
  .bottom-md {
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end
  }
  .around-md {
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around
  }
  .between-md {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between
  }
  .first-md {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
    -webkit-order: -1;
    -ms-flex-order: -1;
    order: -1
  }
  .last-md {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1
  }
}



.col-sm-6 {background:turquoise;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="motability-bg">
        <img src="/img/new-car-template/motab-bg.jpg" alt="motability seat">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="motability-content-bg"></div>
      <div class="motability-content">
        <h1>Motability</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```