# How to arrange 3 divs: div 1 and 2 stacked in left column, and div 3 is right column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got three div's that I'd like to arrange like this

[image]

My code should look like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">Div #1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div #2</div>
    <div class="div3">Div #3</div>    
</div>
```

So - what should my css / html be if at all possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;              /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: column;     /* align children (flex items) vertically */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 120px;
}

.container > div {
    flex: 1 0 50px;            /* occupy free space, don't shrink, initial height */
    width: calc(50% - 10px);   /* half container size less margins */
    margin: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">Div #1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div #2</div>
    <div class="div3">Div #3</div>
</div>
```

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
.main{
    height:500px;
    width:400px;
}
div.subDiv{
    height:50%;
    margin:5px;
}
div.subDiv>div{
    width:47%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.subDiv>div>div{
    height: 122.5px;
    background-color:gray;
}
div.subDiv>div>div+div{
    margin-top:5px
}
.gray{
    background-color:gray;
}
</style>
<div class="main">
    <div class="subDiv">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gray"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result, use following option

```
.container {
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  float: left;
  postion: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
}

.div2 {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
}

.div3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KMWgEz