# Vertically center a textbox in a right-aligned div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

One of the solutions I learned is to set the `display` of the parent div element to `table-cell` and use the `vertical-align` property.

While this works, in my case I also need the parent div to float right, but it breaks the table-cell trick and the whole thing does not work now.

So my question is simple: Why exactly is this happening, and more importantly, how can I achieve the effect I want?

```css
div {
    /* float: right;  uncomment this will make this not working */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input>
</div>
```

[Corresponding JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/3779/)

Comment: There is code demo and its on the OP title, I think it clearly shows it's a textbox. Also please downvoters tell me why the downvotes?

Comment: see @Michael B answer, I think thats what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3 provides flexbox. All you need is this:

```css
body {
    display: flex;              /* create flex container */
    justify-content: flex-end;  /* align child to right edge */
}

div {
    display: flex;              /* create nested flex container */
    align-items: center;        /* center child vertically */
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input>
</div>
```

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Comment: seems great...now I am trying this and will accept once it works :)  Also thanks for the links for self learning.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything with a div set to float:right.

Answer (score 0):

updated your fiddle with few tweaks. hope this works for you.
Please check http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/3780/

html :

```
<div >
<input class="form-control" id="txtWOFastNavigation">
</div>
```

css :

```
div {
   float: right;
    height: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 104px;
}

div .form-control{
     width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```