# Using CSS Flex to Make Elements Equal Height in a Row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make the the elements with yellow background same height as others in that row using `flex`, but cannot figure it out with this design. The `li` elements just dont wan't to be at full height.

Run the code snippet to see what I'm talking about. 
Thank you!

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.liWrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="liWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef ef ewff wef fewf wef few few fwef ewf ewf w</div>
      <div class="body">picture</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="liWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef e</div>
      <div class="body">picture</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="liWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef ef ewff wef fewf wef few few fwef ewf ewf w</div>
      <div class="body">picture</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="liWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Title fwef wef wefwf ewf w</div>
      <div class="body">picture</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="liWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef ef ewfff wefe wfew f wef fewf wef few few fwef ewf ewf w</div>
      <div class="body">picture</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="liWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">Title fwef wef</div>
      <div class="body">Body</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

to `#main` (this also contains an implicit `flex-direction: row;`). You're expecting each of the `.wrapper`'s to be the same height, but you don't have any styling telling them to do that. The `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` on the `.wrapper` simply tells the wrapper to divvy up its height among its child elements. If it's not already the right height, more won't magically appear.

The flex row and wrap makes all child elements equal height by default, which I assume is the behavior you want. :)

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }


        #main{
            width: 90%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .header {
            background: yellow;
            flex: 1;
            font-size: 13px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .body {
            font-size: 13px;
            border: 1px solid orange;
            background: lightblue;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .liWrapper{
            display: inline-flex;
            width: 25%;
            min-width: 25%;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;

        }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="liWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef ef ewff wef fewf wef few few fwef ewf ewf w</div>
            <div class="body">picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="liWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef e</div>
            <div class="body">picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="liWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef ef ewff wef fewf wef few few fwef ewf ewf w</div>
            <div class="body">picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="liWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Title fwef wef wefwf ewf w</div>
            <div class="body">picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="liWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Title fwef wef wef ef ewfff wefe wfew f wef fewf wef few few fwef ewf ewf w</div>
            <div class="body">picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="liWrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Title fwef wef</div>
            <div class="body">Body</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```