# How can I get the quadrants on my page to vertically stretch to match the height of their horizontal neighbor?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, stretching

I want four equi-sized quadrants on my page - all should be the same width and height, with some space between them.

What I'm getting as of now is this:

[image]

What I want is that the top right quadrant ("Pricing Exceptions") stretch vertically, as if being pulled toward the bottom, so that its bottom border lines up horizontally with the top left ("Top 10 Items Purchased") quadrant.

I want similar for the two bottom quadrants, namely that the "Forecasted Spend" quadrant be "pulled down" or "stretched" so that it aligns horizontally wit the taller "Fill Rate" quadrant.

How can I accomplish that?

My code (this is a mockup - all the html and css are combined in one .html file) is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>eServices Customer Dashboard</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Inline CSS (don't tell the CSS-Whisperers I did this!) -->
<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: white;
}
label {
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}
.body-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.addltopmargin {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.sectiontext {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    color: green;
    margin-top: -4px;    
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.marginaboveandbelow {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.rightjustifytext {
  text-align: right;
}
table {
    font-family: georgias, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.contents{
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}
.redfont {
    color: red;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.topleft {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.topright {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding: 16px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.bottomleft {
  margin-left: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.bottomright {
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding: 16px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="contents">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="topleft">
<h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100250</td>
                <td>Artichokes Green Globe 18 Size</td>
                <td>9084</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>102800</td>
                <td>Broccoli Bunched 18 Size</td>
                <td>8837</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100050</td>
                <td>Anise Fennell 12</td>
                <td>6653</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>101600</td>
                <td>Beans Blue Lake Round Hand Pick</td>
                <td>5846</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>106000</td>
                <td>Carrots Cello 48/1#</td>
                <td>4266</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>108000</td>
                <td>Celery Pascal 12</td>
                <td>3774</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>105000</td>
                <td>Cabbage Green 45-50#</td>
                <td>3024</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>104000</td>
                <td>Brussel Sprouts Cello Cups 12/12 oz</td>
                <td>2663</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100450</td>
                <td>Asparagus Colossal 11/1#</td>
                <td>2624</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>102350</td>
                <td>Beets With Tops 24</td>
                <td>2253</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="topright">
<h2 class="sectiontext">Pricing Exceptions - Weekly Recap</h2>
<label class="redfont">Red denotes Contract Item Overages</label>
</br>
<label>For Weyand on the pricing week of - 7/31/2016</label>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Bid Price</th>
                <th>Sell Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>231083</td>
                <td>BERRIES, BLACK DRISC 1/6 OZ</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>4.35</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>104150</td>
                <td>BRUSSEL SPROUTS, 25#</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>36.20</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>261650</td>
                <td>LIMES, 200 CT 40#</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>18.65</td>
                <td>2.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>140000</td>
                <td>MUSHROOMS, BUTTON 10#</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>19.95</td>
                <td>2.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398980</td>
                <td>MELONS, CANTALOUPE CHUNKS 2/5#</td>
                <td>38.30</td>
                <td>35.00</td>
                <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398280</td>
                <td>MELONS, HONEYDEW CHUNKS 2/5#</td>
                <td>37.30</td>
                <td>34.50</td>
                <td>15.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398036</td>
                <td>PINEAPPLE, CHUNKS 2/5#</td>
                <td>37.70</td>
                <td>35.00</td>
                <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>351135</td>
                <td>LETTUCE, SALAD 3-WAY SEP BAG 1/5#</td>
                <td>6.46</td>
                <td>6.01</td>
                <td>2.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>208110</td>
                <td>APPLES, GALA 12 CT</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>8.04</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="bottomleft">
<h2 class="sectiontext">Forecasted Spend</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Last Week's Usage</th>
                <th>This Week's Price</th>
                <th>Forecasted Spend</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>261650</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>3.14</td>
                <td>153.86</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>231083</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>1.25</td>
                <td>65.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398980</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>227.70</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>351135</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0.75</td>
                <td>30.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398036</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>3.00</td>
                <td>126.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>208110</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2.50</td>
                <td>105.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold">TOTAL</td>
                <td class="bold">271</td>
                <td class="bold">--</td>
                <td class="bold">$707.56</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="bottomright">
<h2 class="sectiontext">Fill Rate</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Reason Description</th>
                <th>Ordered</th>
                <th>Shipped</th>
                <th>Rate %</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A11 - PEORIA</td>
                <td>Regular Item, no issues</td>
                <td>622</td>
                <td>622</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A09 - EAST PLANO</td>
                <td>Regular Item, no issues</td>
                <td>371</td>
                <td>375</td>
                <td>101</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A26 - MYRTLE BEACH</td>
                <td>Credit - Product Quality (for credit adjustments only)</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>47</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A38 - LAKELAND</td>
                <td>Regular Item, no issues</td>
                <td>569</td>
                <td>569</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold">TOTAL</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="bold">1581</td>
                <td class="bold">1575</td>
                <td class="bold">99.6</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may be looking for flex equal height columns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Comment: I would advise against Flex as it is not supported by IE... http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: I tried it, adding "display: flex;" to the contents css class, and the result was ignominious - the page looked like the shady schemers after being thrown into the lion's pit following Daniel's being safely lifted out of there - IOW, all chawed up.

Comment: @JPeG, I've got flex working fine in production sites on IE 10, IE 11 and Edge. Saying Flex is not supported by IE is an inaccurate and poorly informed statement, especially when you provide a link to information confirming IE support. Of course, if you're targeting users of IE 9 or older (accounting for less than 1% of global usage, according to your link reference) then flex is not a good option.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, maybe it wasn't implemented properly. Regardless, I'm glad you found your solution.

Comment: @Michael_B It clearly states that IE 10 and 11 only provide partial support with many bugs. You must not run a very important site because abandoning IE9 support is definitely not the norm. We have thousands and thousands of users who still access our sites with IE9.

Comment: @JPeG, in your first comment you say "not supported". In your second comment you're backtracking to "partial support". There's a difference. And the importance of my sites is irrelevant. What matters is the information (or misinformation) posted on this site. You're posting factually incorrect information. That's the only reason I bothered to comment.

Comment: @Michael_B You're just salty cause you recommended they use something that's not fully supported in IE and I called you out on it. Arguing semantics doesn't change anything.

Comment: @JPeG, if you bothered to actually read the answer I recommended, you would see that IE support issues are fully covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't creating dynamic sized containers then you can set the height like so:

```
.topright, .topleft {
height: 400px; 
}
```

This will keep them even.

Comment: I had to alter the size, of course, and also add a pair for the bottoms, but that basically does it.

Answer (score 2):

I usually create my own javascript to check each row. I give all divs that should have the same height (in your case the `col-md-6` divs) an additional class: `match-height` (a ripoff of the existing plugin `matchHeight.js`).

This code will loop through all `.row` divs and see which `.match-height` div is the highest. After this is done the code will adjust all those divs to the highest div giving it `min-height` CSS.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function equalHeights() {

  $('.row').each(function(){
    var highestBox = 0;
    $(this).find('.match-height').css("min-height", 0);
    $(this).find('.match-height').each(function() {
      if ($(this).outerHeight() > highestBox) {
        highestBox = $(this).outerHeight();
      }
    });
    $(this).find('.match-height').css("min-height", highestBox);
  });

});
```

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 match-height">
      1st table
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 match-height">
      2nd table
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 match-height">
      3rd table
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 match-height">
      4th table
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for,

Comment: Cool, looks applicable.

Comment: Also, this answer is interesting. using CSS only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Answer (score 1):

Took me lot of time and I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>eServices Customer Dashboard</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Inline CSS (don't tell the CSS-Whisperers I did this!) -->
<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: white;
}
label {
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, Georgia, serif;
}
.body-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.addltopmargin {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.sectiontext {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    color: green;
    margin-top: -4px;    
}
.bottommarginbreathingroom {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.marginaboveandbelow {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.rightjustifytext {
  text-align: right;
}
table {
    font-family: georgias, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    align:center;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.contents{
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}
.redfont {
    color: red;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.topleft {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-right:19px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom:16px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:500px;

}
.topright {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 15px;

  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom:16px;
  height:500px;

  border:1px solid black;
}
.bottomleft {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-right:18px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom:16px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:385px;
}
.bottomright {
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:15px;




  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom:16px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:385px;
}
#xyz{


}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="contents">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
<div class="topleft">
<h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>
        <div>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangefrom2" name="daterangefrom2">
            </input>
            <label> to </label>
            <input type="date" class="bottommarginbreathingroom" id="daterangeto2" name="daterangeto2">
            </input>
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100250</td>
                <td>Artichokes Green Globe 18 Size</td>
                <td>9084</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>102800</td>
                <td>Broccoli Bunched 18 Size</td>
                <td>8837</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100050</td>
                <td>Anise Fennell 12</td>
                <td>6653</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>101600</td>
                <td>Beans Blue Lake Round Hand Pick</td>
                <td>5846</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>106000</td>
                <td>Carrots Cello 48/1#</td>
                <td>4266</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>108000</td>
                <td>Celery Pascal 12</td>
                <td>3774</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>105000</td>
                <td>Cabbage Green 45-50#</td>
                <td>3024</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>104000</td>
                <td>Brussel Sprouts Cello Cups 12/12 oz</td>
                <td>2663</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>100450</td>
                <td>Asparagus Colossal 11/1#</td>
                <td>2624</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>102350</td>
                <td>Beets With Tops 24</td>
                <td>2253</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="topright">

<h2 class="sectiontext">Pricing Exceptions - Weekly Recap</h2>
<label class="redfont">Red denotes Contract Item Overages</label>
</br>
<label>For Weyand on the pricing week of - 7/31/2016</label>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Bid Price</th>
                <th>Sell Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>231083</td>
                <td>BERRIES, BLACK DRISC 1/6 OZ</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>4.35</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>104150</td>
                <td>BRUSSEL SPROUTS, 25#</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>36.20</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>261650</td>
                <td>LIMES, 200 CT 40#</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>18.65</td>
                <td>2.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>140000</td>
                <td>MUSHROOMS, BUTTON 10#</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>19.95</td>
                <td>2.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398980</td>
                <td>MELONS, CANTALOUPE CHUNKS 2/5#</td>
                <td>38.30</td>
                <td>35.00</td>
                <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398280</td>
                <td>MELONS, HONEYDEW CHUNKS 2/5#</td>
                <td>37.30</td>
                <td>34.50</td>
                <td>15.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398036</td>
                <td>PINEAPPLE, CHUNKS 2/5#</td>
                <td>37.70</td>
                <td>35.00</td>
                <td>10.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>351135</td>
                <td>LETTUCE, SALAD 3-WAY SEP BAG 1/5#</td>
                <td>6.46</td>
                <td>6.01</td>
                <td>2.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>208110</td>
                <td>APPLES, GALA 12 CT</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>8.04</td>
                <td>1.00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><br/></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"><br/></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" >
<div class="bottomleft" >
<h2 class="sectiontext">Forecasted Spend</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Last Week's Usage</th>
                <th>This Week's Price</th>
                <th>Forecasted Spend</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>261650</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>3.14</td>
                <td>153.86</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>231083</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>1.25</td>
                <td>65.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398980</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>4.95</td>
                <td>227.70</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>351135</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>0.75</td>
                <td>30.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>398036</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>3.00</td>
                <td>126.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>208110</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2.50</td>
                <td>105.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold">TOTAL</td>
                <td class="bold">271</td>
                <td class="bold">--</td>
                <td class="bold">$707.56</td>



            </tr>




        </table >
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="bottomright">
<h2 class="sectiontext">Fill Rate</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Reason Description</th>
                <th>Ordered</th>
                <th>Shipped</th>
                <th>Rate %</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A11 - PEORIA</td>
                <td>Regular Item, no issues</td>
                <td>622</td>
                <td>622</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A09 - EAST PLANO</td>
                <td>Regular Item, no issues</td>
                <td>371</td>
                <td>375</td>
                <td>101</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A26 - MYRTLE BEACH</td>
                <td>Credit - Product Quality (for credit adjustments only)</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>47</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ABUELOS #A38 - LAKELAND</td>
                <td>Regular Item, no issues</td>
                <td>569</td>
                <td>569</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold">TOTAL</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="bold">1581</td>
                <td class="bold">1575</td>
                <td class="bold">99.6</td>


            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"><br/></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"><br/></div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tut tut tut inline css tut tut tut

Answer (score 1):

Because the height of each container is automatically increased as the content increases. As the four tables have different content, you can set a fixed height to solve the problem.