# Layout of 3 DIVs, where 2 are in one column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make something like this:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------|-------------|
|                                                        |             |
|                    DIV 1                               |             |
|                                                        |    DIV 3    |
|--------------------------------------------------------|             |
|                    DIV 2                               |             |
|--------------------------------------------------------|-------------|
```

I can't use a table for this. And I don't know if there's a way to just let them stack like that?

I tried it with the code below, but DIV 3 is not all the way at the top. It is actually exactly div2.height lower from the top.

```css
#DIV_1 {
  height: 125px;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#DIV_2 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
}
#DIV_3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 140px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="width: 1024px; height: 140px;">
  <div>
    <div id="DIV_1"></div>
    <div id="DIV_2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="DIV_3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you can use bootstrap grid system for that.

Comment: So many different ways to achieve this. you don't need to declare display block on a div. Unless you are overwriting something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. I removed float and width from DIV_1 and DIV_2 and put it on the parent.

```css
#DIV_0 {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

#DIV_1 {
  height: 125px;
}

#DIV_2 {
  height: 15px;
}

#DIV_3 {
  float: left;
  height: 140px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="width: 1024px; height: 140px;">

  <div id="DIV_0">
    <div id="DIV_1">div1</div>
    <div id="DIV_2">div2</div>
  </div>

  <div id="DIV_3">
    div3
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job! I see how it does the thing now :)

Answer (score 10):

The layout is relatively simple with CSS flexbox:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;                 /* establish flex container */
    height: 140px;                 /* height from original code */
    width: 1024px;                 /* width from original code */
}

.row > div:first-child {
    flex: 0 0 80%;                 /* width from original code */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;        /* stack first div children vertically */
}

.row > div:first-child > div {
    flex: 1;                       /* items in first div distribute space equally */
    border: 1px dashed black; 
}

.row > div:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div id="DIV_1">DIV #1</div>
        <div id="DIV_2">DIV #2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_3">DIV #3</div>
</div>
```

---

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*Browser support:*

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

Answer (score 4):

Do not use floating with `#DIV_1`. Instead use `float: left, width: 80%` with the parent of `#DIV_1`.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend using [Bootstrap Grid](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">DIV 1</div>
      <div class="row">DIV 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4>DIV 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with twitter's bootstrap. Link to the bootstrap online:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Then you can use the below code to accomplish that:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-8">           
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using bootstrap but I have my other styles setup that two together on that part become really wonky...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        #one img, #two img{width: 300px;
                        height: 300px;}

        #three img{height: 600px;
                width: 600px;}

        div#onetwo, div#three{display: inline-block;}

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="onetwo">
        <div id="one"><img src="image1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div id="two"><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></div>

     </div>

     <div id="three"><img src="image3.png" alt=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

or use bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using pure CSS with CSS Grid.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="row-1">
      row 1
    </div>
    <div class="row-2">
      row 2
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-2">
    column 2
  </div>
</main>
```

The benefit I find of using CSS grid is that it takes very few CSS rules if your HTML is defined well.

CSS Tricks has an in-depth [Guide to CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) which includes browser support information (now implemented in most modern browsers).