# Make height of the children same inside flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with `display: flex` and two children div say `.left` and `.right`.
The content size of the `.left` and `.right` are different. I want to **set same height for the children**

here is a minimal working code

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center
}
.left, .right{
 width: 50%;
}
.right{
 background: blue;
 height: 100%;
}
.left{
 background: green;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  <span>this dis also should have same width as right div</span>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL5scvsg/)** for the question

**Note**: Prefer a solution without applying `position: absolute` as it will destroy my actual website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the height:100%; it will fix the issue .. flexbox apply its height in children itself.

Comment: remove align-item: center also. here is the fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/mL5scvsg/1/

Comment: and if you want to left side text center .. then you need to make it also display:flex and apply align- item on it .. here is the fiddle for this .. https://jsfiddle.net/mL5scvsg/2/