# Calculate div height

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make two `div`s the same height. But one div is smaller one while one is taller. Can someone explain how I can make them always the same?

Have some code here:

```
$(function() {
  var a = $(.box1);
  var b = $(.box2);

  function calcHeight(a, b){
   if (a.height() > b.height()) {
    b.css("height", a);
   } else {
    a.css("height", b);
   }
  }

   calcHeight(a,b)

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
  calcHeight(a,b)
  })
})
<div class="flexcontainer"> ---rows are in flex-direction: row;
 <div class="row1"> --- boxes are one below other 
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="row2"> 
  <div class="box3"></div> --- This box is full-height 
 </div> 
 <div class="row3"> --- boxes are one below other
  <div class="box4"></div> 
  <div class="box5"></div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

I want `box5` and `box2` to be always the same height.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need JS for equal height divs. You can use CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Comment: `a` is your jQuery object, `a.height()` is the height value

Comment: As mentioned: b.css("height", a); is problem -> you are setting css height value to object it self, but you need height value, so:   b.css("height", a.height()+'px'); and so on...

Comment: @Michael_B Well, as long as they are on 1 line :) ... which we don't know in this case

Comment: If you post the markup and CSS, we will be able to provide a proper answer

Comment: @LGSon im edited my answer, you can check. thank you!

Comment: @LGSon

I have some idea. How can I go through every box with specific class, look for biggest height, took height and put on every box?

P. S. On every resize and reload too.

THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following :

```js
$(function() {
  var a = $('.box1');
  var b = $('.box2');

  function calcHeight(a, b){
   var max_height = Math.max(a.height(), b.height())+'px';
   a.css('height', max_height);
   b.css('height', max_height);
  }

   calcHeight(a,b)

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    calcHeight(a,b)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer"> ---rows are in flex-direction: row;
 <div class="row1"> --- boxes are one bolow other 
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="row2"> 
  <div class="box3"></div> --- This box is full-height 
 </div> 
 <div class="row3"> --- boxes are one bolow other
  <div class="box4"></div> 
  <div class="box5"></div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TklnTky

Hm, I have some idea. How can i go through every box with specific class, look for highest box, took highest heigh and put it on every box?

For every resize and reload too. 

THANK YOU!

Comment: Hmm .. add the same class to all your boxes, calculate the biggest height ( loop over all of them, store the biggest one ), and then apply this height to all your boxes.
$('.box').each(function() { if(max_height < $(this).height()) { max_height = $(this).height(); } 
$('.box').css('height': max_height+'px');

Comment: @TklnTky I have this code and min-height: 310px; in CSS

$(function() {

  function setEqualHeight(className) {
    var max = 0;

    $(className).each(function( index ) {
        var current = $(this).height();

        if (current > max) {
          max = current;
        }
    });

    $(className).css('height',  max + 'px');
  }

  var boxUnit = '.box1';

  $(window).on('load',setEqualHeight(boxUnit));
  $(window).on('resize',setEqualHeight(boxUnit));
})

And it set me on reload on 1920px height: 310px; and this height is on every lower beakpoint.

Comment: @TklnTky While I have different min-heights for every breakpoint