# Vertical align two columns, a shorter and a longer text

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

here is a simplified fiddle of what I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/acolombo/xxab2345/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="DivB">Just another text.</div>
    <div id="DivA">Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text.Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text. Lots and lots of text.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#DivA {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}
#DivB {
    float: right;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I've tried in many ways to vertical align the shorter text with the longer one keeping everything responsive but I can't seem to find a valid solution.

All the similar questions I found use something not dynamic, let's say a fixed width, height, margin or anything else, and these solutions won't work for my problem. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to write that the shorter line still needs to keep its size like in the example I posted, the longer text needs to shrink besides it
 while it stays still

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of flexbox, you can use `display: table;` and `vertical-align` http://jsfiddle.net/xxab2345/2/

Or even `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align`
http://jsfiddle.net/xxab2345/3/

Comment: The first solution is almost working, I have to keep the shortest line of text on one line though, but I forgot to say it before. Well, it just needs to keep its dimension, and the other text continue to shrtink. I missed this important information because my fiddle already did that, sorry.

Comment: add `white-space:nowrap;` to the element where you don't want the words to break. http://jsfiddle.net/xxab2345/5/

Answer (score 0):

The magic you are looking for is `display: flex` :)

Apply it to both divs, and they will have equal heights.
An updated fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/nfLza6ts/).

Note that if you want to change the order of your DIVs, you will have to swap their position in the HTML, as `float` won't work with `display:flex` :)

**Update Based On Question Revision**:

To have the shorter div display all the text on the same line, all you need to do is add `white-space: nowrap;` to it.

An updated fiddle showcasing this new behaviour can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/nfLza6ts/1/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I missed something initally in my question, I have to keep the shortest line of text on one line. Well, it just needs to keep its dimension, and the other text continue to shrink. I missed this important information because my fiddle already did that, sorry.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this issue -- hopefully this is the behaviour you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Any easier way would be to use `float:left;`

```
.container>div{float:left;}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6onazzuu/1/)